# Node.js version on the command line? (not the REPL)

Tags: node.js, command-line

I want to get the version of Node.js on the command line. I'm expecting to run a command like:

```
node -version
```

but that doesn't work. Does anybody know what the command line would be? (i.e. not the REPL)

Comment: Yes, the runtime question works for the Node command line, not the shell.  Of course, "command line" could refer to either thing.

Comment: Check `node --help`. But, in short, you need 2 dashes for full-name options: `node --version`. A single dash starts a group of aliases, so `-version` combines `-v`, `-e`, `-r`, etc -- though only 3 of the 7 are recognized by Node.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Good to know about `node --help` (`node -h` works too). However, `node` does _not_ support _grouping_ of options the way you describe; e.g., `node -p -i` works (syntactically - as of 0.12, no combination of short options makes sense semantically), but `node -pi` results in an `unrecognized flag` / `bad option` (0.12) error.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41814019/1042705) may help somebody!

Answer (score 1232, accepted):

The command line for that is:

```
node -v
```

Or

```
node --version
```

Note:

If `node -v` doesn't work, but `nodejs -v` does, then something's not set up quite right on your system. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04) for ways to fix it.

Comment: In the year 2015, this no longer works. Use `nodejs -v` instead.

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin `node -v` does work. I'm using latest version available today which is 0.12.6.

Comment: This works in 6.8.0:
`>node -v`
`v6.8.0`
`>node --version`
`v6.8.0`

Comment: node -v => 
v8.11.2 =>
So this works also for v8.11.2

Answer (score 87):

If you're referring to the shell command line, either of the following will work:

```
node -v

node --version
```

Just typing `node version` will cause node.js to attempt loading a module named version, which doesn't exist unless you like working with confusing module names.

Comment: You're welcome. Note, however, that the OP typed `node -version`, not `node version`. The former reports an `unrecognized flag` / `bad option` (in 0.12) error and then  enters the REPL, whereas the latter indeed tries to load a non-existent file, and aborts without entering the REPL. @JonathanLonowski has already stated it in a comment on the question, but let me repeat it here: `node -h` or `node --help` shows all supported command-line options.

Answer (score 41):

Try  `nodejs` instead of just `node`

```
$ nodejs -v
v0.10.25
```

Comment: Note: The node.js executable (binary) should be `node`, not `nodejs`. However, there was a naming conflict on some Linux distros (e.g., Ubuntu), resulting in the executable getting installed as `nodejs`. As of Ubuntu 14.04, for instance, `apt-get install nodejs` will _also_ install executable `node` (implemented as a symlink to `nodejs`). In other words: For consistency, _try `node -v` first_.

Answer (score 33):

Just type `npm version` in your command line and it will display all the version details about node, npm, v8 engine etc.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

> > Repl Command to find the Nodejs Version

```
$node
>process.version
`v8.x`
```

Comment: The question title literally says "NOT THE REPL"

Answer (score 15):

**Node**:

`node --version` or `node -v`

**npm**:

`npm --version` or `npm -v`

**V8 engine version**:

```
node -p process.versions.v8
```

Answer (score 11):

find the installed node version.

```
$ node --version
```

or

```
 $ node -v
```

And if you want more information about installed node(i.e. node version,v8 version,platform,env variables info etc.)

then just do this.

```
$ node
> process
  process {
  title: 'node',
  version: 'v6.6.0',
  moduleLoadList: 
   [ 'Binding contextify',
     'Binding natives',
     'NativeModule events',
     'NativeModule util',
     'Binding uv',
     'NativeModule buffer',
     'Binding buffer',
     'Binding util',
     ...
```

where The process object is a global that provides information about, and control over, the current Node.js process.

Comment: `>process.version` will only show the version and not the full process object

Answer (score 5):

By default node package is nodejs, so use

```
$ nodejs -v
```

or

```
$ nodejs --version
```

You can make a link using

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

then u can use

```
$ node --version
```

or

```
$ node -v
```

Comment: This naming inconsistency in some distros was already noted in a 2014 answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26622019

Answer (score 5):

One cool tip if you are using the Atom editor.

```
$ apm -v
apm  1.12.5
npm  3.10.5
node 4.4.5
python 2.7.12
git 2.7.4
```

It will return you not only the node version but also few other things.

Comment: apm -v will tell you the version of node and npm that Atom is using. It may not necessarily be the one that will be if you are using the command line

Answer (score 2):

On November 2023 this command is working perfect:

```
node -v
```

[image: Note date and time at the command prompt]

Note date and time at the command prompt on this screen capture. So there's no ambiguity on node or nodejs. It seems it has been standardized long ago and it still works as shown here.

Node has some kind of an issue with its dependent frameworks and utilities and version management has been a must for me since it gained popularity. I often needed to review old code that didn't run on the version I was using at present time.

The solution was node version manager "nvm" you can install from github: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm this tool will inform you of your node version and will allow you to change it temporarily or as often as you need.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Nico, this is not the same answer. There are two main differences: 1. is a confirmation on that on 2023 november, the command is still working (not nodejs -v) 2. Proposal of nvm as a version manager. Or is it that you need more badges or reputation points??

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. And no, I don't gain any badge or reputation point

Comment: That `node -v` is working was already written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/39790080/1116230 seven years ago. Posting that information again does not provide any additional benefit. And how does nvm relate to the given question?

Comment: Still on the same? It doesn't provide any information that you can still use the same command seven years later? (some answers suggested there was a variation along time). And NVM is a wonderful tool to, not only get the current version, but manage what has been a long time node issue: some of their dependent utilities are version linked. And the question itself is about versioning, so why should NVM not be relevant.?

Comment: I was following someone's answers and finished here. I just tried to add my grain, but I'm at one step to delete it all. Writing at SO has become a time wasting experience, it doesn't make sense anymore.