# nodejs vs node on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, serverside-javascript

I installed nodejs on ubuntu from instructions given [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint)

When I write `node --version` in the terminal I see this : 
`-bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory`

I can see node in the `/usr/sbin/` directory, though.

Writing `npm --version` shows `1.3.5` 
Writing `nodejs --version` shows `v0.10.15`

Also, I can see node in the `/usr/bin/` directory.

So, how do I get `node` working?

Also, If I use *zsh* instead of bash, then `node` command works.

Comment: If "you see node in /usr/bin/", then what is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/node`?

Comment: @randunel I got this output `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan  1  2013 /usr/bin/node -> /etc/alternatives/node`

Comment: Did you make any changes to shell rc?

Comment: This looks like a shell problem after your edit, what does `export | grep PATH` output when not using `zsh`? (it should print `/usr/bin` among other things)

Comment: It printed a bunch of paths. One of them is `declare -x NODE_PATH="/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript"`

Comment: Sorry, I'm interested in this output: `declare -x PATH=".....`, not `NODE_PATH`, just `PATH`

Comment: `declare -x PATH="/home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/home/jatin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/home/jatin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/home/jatin/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"`

Comment: Well, the path looks correct, you should see the `node` executable file from anywhere. When you type `whereis node`, what's the output?

Comment: `whereis node` gives `node: /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/X11/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz` and `which node` gives `/usr/bin/node`

Comment: I give up :D You see node and it prints `No such file or directory` when attempting to run it. You should ask about this at `http://unix.stackexchange.com/`, since it does not seem to be `nodejs` related.

Comment: The error says `-bash: /usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory` . Although `usr/sbin/` is also in PATH. Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: solution + explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168141/cannot-install-packages-using-node-package-manager-in-ubuntu/21171188#21171188

Answer (score 613, accepted):

You need to manually create a symlink `/usr/bin/node`. Shortcut for bash compatible shells:

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```

Or if you use non-standard shells, just hardcode the path you find with `which nodejs`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

**Later edit**

I found this explanation in the link you posted

> There is a naming conflict with the node package (Amateur Packet Radio Node Program), and the nodejs binary has been renamed from node to nodejs. You'll need to symlink /usr/bin/node to /usr/bin/nodejs or you could uninstall the Amateur Packet Radio Node Program to avoid that conflict.

**Later later edit**

It's been a while since I answered this. Although the solution I posted up here worked for me several times, users have reported a few more solutions within the comments:

From @user229115

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10`

From AskUbuntu (user leftium)

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: okay! Although, if I use `zsh`, then the `node` command works.

Comment: Also, how do I uninstall the Amateur Packet Radio Node program? I tried `sudo apt-get remove node` but it says `Package node is not installed, so not removed`

Comment: You don't need to uninstall it, after your comments, this looks like a shell problem, not a node package problem.

Comment: @randunel's answer did not work for me as `/usr/bin/env node` would not work. @BennyMcBenBen's solution did work

Comment: I needed to make the symlink in sbin

$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node

Comment: Thanks randunel, i just echoed my `$PATH `first by using

    `echo $PATH`

And then i created a symlink for my applications executable in one of the paths like `/usr/local/bin`  ..works awesome..

Comment: @Tino's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20929278/1424087) is the right one, see the `nodejs-legacy` package's description. The answer linked by @BennyMcBenBen has been updated with similar instructions too.

Comment: Then as module developer i confuse which one i have to use on npm run scripts

Comment: The irony is that the Amateur Packet Radio Node program changed their products names. Changing node to nodejs should be in the book of top 10 software blunders of the century. Such a mess. Despite Windows dominating the desktop market, this name change breaks so many things on Windows as it expects the shebang to be node not nodejs.. They need to eat crow and put the name back.

Comment: On Ubuntu server, just installed nodejs and then used `sudo ln -s \`which nodejs\` /usr/sbin/node`. `/usr/sbin` being the difference for a server of this kind. Might be helpful to some hopefully :)

Answer (score 90):

I think this is it:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10
```

Using Debian alternatives.

Comment: This seems to be the better option than the accepted answer a it doesn't manually changes the /usr/bin/ folder and is using the infrastructure to alternative commands

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I looked at the `update-alternative` docs. If it really works, then it's a better solution :)

Comment: can you be more specific as to what this is doing?

Comment: @DominikFretz meh. The end result is _exactly_ the same using Debian-specific command versus a POSIX compliant one. (You could have done `update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/fribjazt node /usr/bin/nodejs 10`.) To each his own, but I prefer the plain `ln`.

Comment: I had to `source ~/.bashrc` for this to take effect

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is a much cleaner and self-explanatory approach. Still works in 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04, node v7.3.0 and npm v4.6.1. Never install nodejs from Ubuntu's default repos! Thanks for awesome answer @user229115

Comment: @AnthonyKong: Accoding to `man update-alternatives`, the `10` is the priority of the alternative.

Answer (score 68):

Apparently the solution differs between Ubuntu versions.  Following worked for me on Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

HTH

Edit: **Rule of thumb:**

**If you have installed `nodejs` but are missing the `/usr/bin/node` binary, then also install `nodejs-legacy`.**  This just creates the missing softlink.

According to my tests, Ubuntu 17.10 and above already have the compatibility-softlink `/usr/bin/node` in place after `nodejs` is installed, so `nodejs-legacy` is missing from these releases as it is no more needed.

Comment: it seems nodejs-legacy is not maintained anymore. latest build stops at 2013-04-10

Comment: `nodejs-legacy` needs not much maintainance.  It just adds a softlink similar to `sudo ln -s nodejs /usr/bin/node`, at least on LTS 14.04

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, nodejs and nodejs-legacy install the same version of Node (0.10.25). +1 to @Tino.

Comment: Works for me in Debian Jessie as well. This should be the accepted answer as this is how things are meant to be. Only people using the amateur radio package should not do this. I'm wondering why they didn't rename the radio package like they did with chromium-bsu.

Comment: This will result in 2 instances of node on your system and this is no longer maintained... Recommend you link to nodejs instead.

Comment: @Hariboo (Rule of thumb added to my answer.)  I tried with Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04 and 16.04. `nodejs-legacy` does not install a second package, it just creates a softlink of `/usr/bin/node` which points to `/usr/bin/nodejs`.  There is no much need to "maintain" a softlink, hence it can be "unmaintained".  `nodejs-legacy` is missing in Ubuntu 17.10 as well as in (upcoming) Ubuntu 18.04, because `nodejs` now includes the softlink, which previously was in `nodejs-legacy`, so there is no more need for `nodejs-legacy`.

Answer (score 30):

I have the same issue in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have installed "nodejs" and it's working, but only if I'm use command "nodejs". If I try to use "node" nothing happens.

I'm fixed this problem in next way:

1. Install nodejs-legacy

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
   ```

After that, when I type "node" in command line I'm get an error message "/usr/sbin/node: No such file or directory"

2. Second, what I did, it's a symbolic link on "nodejs":

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/sbin/node
   ```

Comment: There is somethings weird on your system.  `node` is supposed to be installed into `/usr/bin/` and not `/usr/sbin/`.  It looks for me as if you had installed the Ubuntu `node` package from hamradio before (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/node/filelist) and forgot to run `hash -r` on shell level, such that the shell still remembered the wrong path.  The second `ln` fixed that as well, but it is no more needed after you leave that shell.

Comment: BTW, even wrong answers are good to explain all the trouble due to three packages all of very similar names: `node` (`/usr/sbin/node` for something completely different), `nodejs` (`/usr/bin/nodejs`) and `nodejs-legacy` (`/usr/bin/node`, depends on package `nodejs`).

Comment: This happened to me as well.  I had installed node from source some time ago.  `node -v => 0.10.2` while `nodejs -v => 5.5.0`. Running the command `which node` always pointed to this local installation.  In the end, I had to `unset NODE_PATH`, which pointed to the local installation to fix it.  After this, `node -v => 5.5.0` and `npm install`  started to work for packages depending on Node => 5.0.

Answer (score 12):

#### Node Version Manager (nvm)

If you like to install multiple nodejs versions and easily switch between them, I would suggest using [Node Version Manger](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). It also solves the naming problem (`node` vs `nodejs`)

It's quite simple:

Install a nodejs version:

```
$ nvm install 4.4
```

Now you have nodejs 4.4 in addition to the version that was already installed and you can just use the `node` command to reach the newly installed version:

```
$ node -v    // The new version added by nvm.
v4.4.5
$ nodejs -v  // The OS version is untouched and still available.
v0.10.25
```

You can install more nodejs versions and easily switch between them:

```
$ nvm install 6.2
$ nvm use 6.2
Now using node v6.2.1 (npm v3.9.3)
$ node -v
v6.2.1
$ nvm use 4.4
Now using node v4.4.5 (npm v2.15.5)
```

Comment: That's resolved my issue, thanks a lot, I found some useful command for `nvm` on [How To Install Node.js on an Ubuntu 14.04 server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server)

Comment: this worked for me.  Also a guide available here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server#how-to-install-using-nvm

Answer (score 11):

This happened to me as well.

```
node -v => 0.10.2
nodejs -v => 5.5.0
```

The issue was that I had installed node from source some time ago. Running

```
which node
```

always pointed to this local installation. Also,

```
echo NODE_PATH
```

pointed to the local installation.

deleting the directory with the source install didn't help. It just broke the node command.  In the end, unsetting the NODE_PATH environmental variable and purging then reinstalling nodejs did the trick.

```
unset NODE_PATH
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

After this,

```
node -v => 5.5.0
```

and npm install started to work for packages depending on Node => 5.0.

Comment: This worked for me. Too bad I messed around for an hour before finding it.

Answer (score 10):

I am new to all this, but for me a simple alias worked:

```
alias node='env NODE_NO_READLINE=1 rlwrap nodejs'
```

at least for running things directly in bash and executing .js files.

Comment: Worked without `rlwrap`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Phill, you are awesome!

Answer (score 9):

**How about using the official instructions from the [nodejs site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)**:

For v7:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

For v6:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

For v4:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I've tested these from Windows bash (via subsystem for Linux - 14.04) and raspbian (ARM Debian based). Running `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` without first running the setup script will result in you getting node 0.10.

If you are planning on installing native npm modules requiring build, also run:

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential
```

<sup>Note: this is the recommended path for any Debian based distro across all architectures.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Adding to @randunel's correct answer (can't yet comment on SO):

I also had to symlink /usr/local/bin/node to /usr/bin/nodejs as well.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

Apparently, this was overriding the /usr/bin/ node command.

No idea how that got set, but hope it helps someone else as it was a pain to figure out why the above wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 7):

Late answer, but for up-to-date info...

If you install node.js using the recommend method from the [node github installation readme](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager), it suggests following the instructions on the [nodesource blog article](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories), rather than installing from the out of date apt-get repo, node.js should run using the `node` command, as well as the `nodejs` command, without having to make a new symlink.

This method from article is:

```bash
# Note the new setup script name for Node.js v0.12
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -

# Then install with:
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Note that this is for v0.12, which will get likely become outdated in the not to distant future.

Also, if you're behind a corporate proxy (like me) you'll want to add the -E option to the sudo command, to preserve the env vars required for the proxy:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo -E bash -`

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
alias node=nodejs
```

After following the instructions in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) link.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on an AWS EC2 instance running an Ubuntu instance (tested on Ubuntu 16.x), then these steps might work for you:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get --purge remove node -y
    sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs -y
    sudo apt-get --purge remove legacy-node -y
    sudo rm  /usr/bin/node
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -
    sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
    node -v
```

If all is correct the last command shall have an output like : v6.x.x

If not then run the following:

```
    sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Hopefully this will help. It helped me magically (hehe).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue symbolic link helped me out:
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
after that 
sudo npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt

went smoothly

Answer (score 2):

Best way to install nodejs is through NVM (Node Version Manager)

Delete previous versions :

```
$ sudo apt-get purge node
```

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

Also delete all node_modules by `$ sudo rm -rf node_modules` in the directory containing this folder.

Node & Nodejs are technically the same thing. Just the naming changed.

First Install or update nvm

to run as root

```
$ sudo su
```

Then

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.7/install.sh | bash
```

OR

```
$ wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.7/install.sh | bash
```

Check nvm to path

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

```
$ nvm ls-remote
```

if you get error regarding the listing then install git.

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

Re-run :

```
$ nvm ls-remote
```

OR

```
$ sudo nvm ls-remote
```

```
$ nvm install version-you-require
```

Checking Version

```
# node --version
```

```
nvm use version-you-require
```

INFORMATION COURTESY :

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps
```

Answer (score 1):

I had created a symlink, but it still wasn't working.

I forgot to restart my terminal (my putty connection). After I had it worked without the symlink :)

Answer (score 1):

> Will be helpful for absolute beginners

Although, you have got the answer, just wanted to point out that the `node` command (without any parameters) will start node in REPL <sub>read-eval-print-loop</sub> mode to execute raw javascript code.

Another way to use `node` command is by providing it a `js` file as a parameter. This is how we mostly use it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use NVM(Node Version Manager) - 
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

It has become the standard for managing Node.js.

When you need a new version:

```
nvm install NEW_VER
nvm use XXX
```

If something goes wrong you can always go back with

```
nvm use OLD_VER
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute this command to enable nodejs:

```
scl enable rh-nodejs8 bash
```

Note: Check your node version.

**Source:**
https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world/

Answer (score 1):

***https://nodejs.org/en/download/***

```
Download .pkg file on your mac and install it. it directly works.

➜  ~ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
➜  ~ node --version
v10.11.0
➜  ~ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
➜  ~ npm --version
6.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's optional to remove the existing node and nodejs, but have to do alternatively install the latest 7.x nodejs.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I just used this

```
sudo npm cache clean -f

sudo npm install -g n

sudo n stable
```

This one will Install a Stable Version

Then just make it symlink

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/local/bin/node
```

Answer (score -1):

- First install the recommended version
- Try in cmd `node -v`
- If command work than try it in vs command
- If it still not working "check path " in environment variable;
- If env is set than recheck if it is working or not;
- Then just shutdown your computer and restart it.
- Then try it "i hope it will work "

-***Restart is very important***
to run program properly in vs.