# Failed to load c++ bson extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, dependencies

A total node noob here. I've been trying to set up a sample node app but the following error keeps popping up every time I try to run:

> **node app**

```
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: failed to connect to [#$%67890 :27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/thejazeto/code/nodejs/authen/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:553:74)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/thejazeto/code/nodejs/authen/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/thejazeto/code/nodejs/authen/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:512:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:830:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: The error is `failed to connect to`, so I think that `bson` message may be unrelated and not actually matter. Are you sure your Mongo connection settings are correct?

Comment: Funny story I only get this error on a windows machine... havent tried installing node-gyp but ive tried almost everything else and still getting the error. and chocoletey wont install build essentials

Comment: Isn't the JS BSON code almost as fast as the C++ now?  If so, is this really a problem?

Comment: For people on newer iojs experiencing this issue, I have opened a ticket to track this issue: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/136

Comment: Note: I am using Keystone.js as my mvc framework. For me, you change "../build/Release/bson" to "../browser_build/bson". If you go up, you see the browser_build folder.

Answer (score 201):

I guess you did not have the make tools available when you installed your mongodb library. I suggest you do

`xcode-select --install` (on a mac)
or `sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential` (on ubuntu)

and run

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

OR just npm update based on @tobias comment (after installing build-essential)

```
npm update
```

Comment: +1. All I had to do was the last 3 lines - I think the reason mine wasn't built was because it came as part of the `mongoskin` module.

Comment: Wow!   That ``sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential`` tip is one of the best Node.js + Ubuntu development tips I've ever seen.  It's an absolute game-changer if you're used to development web applications and just developing with Node.js on Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the reason of installing `gcc` and `make` along with `build-essential`? The latter depends on the other two so they're going to be installed anyway (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/build-essential). Doing `sudo apt-get install build-essential` should be enough.

Comment: try re-installing mongoose: `npm install mongoose --save`

Comment: Problem is still here on osx yosomite.

Comment: That's a quick solution. `xcode-select --install` on mac and then `npm update` fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: How about on windows??
I am getting something like this on my windows command prompt 
C:\Users\me>node C:\Users\me\Desktop\nodeproject\datagen.js
 { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Connected correctly to server

Comment: Is there a way to make it a correct answer?  This happens on my mac once and my ubuntu now and I solved the problem with this solution both times.

Comment: What about window machines :(

Comment: For people on newer iojs experiencing this issue, I have opened a ticket to track this issue: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/136

Answer (score 100):

I just resolved that.

When you install the mongoose module by npm, it does not have a built bson module in it's folder. In the file `node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js`, change the line

```
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

to

```
bson = require('bson');
```

and then install the bson module using npm.

Comment: is it a good idea to change things inside the node_modules directory? That seems brittle

Comment: @DouglasFerguson Not really. If you edit a node_module, I'd suggest forking the repo and installing your modified module via npm/bower.

Comment: Yes. I agree. I was just pointing out that the previous advice could encourage others to edit node_modules directly.

Comment: This answer worked. Devs at Mongoose, please fix this!

Comment: This is a hack, not a fix.

Comment: This is not a solution. With the same result you can just remove strings which prints error. This error appears because of native c++ plugin for bson not found and in this case js realization will be used anyway.

Comment: I was doing this on a release of [DietPi](http://fuzon.co.uk/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=6) on a 512MB RP1. Just wanted to mentioned that I had to install **Python** (`apt-get install python`) and then from within `node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/` run `make`. This created `Release/bson.node`.

Comment: Solved my problem here. Better make a fork to have this fix.

Comment: But then I updated connect-mongo to 0.8.2 and mongoose to version 4.0.7, and it worked without the hack!

Comment: I did this change and it worked only if I replace all the files containing the "require('../build/Release/bson')" to require('bson'). The files that I changed are: node_modules/mean-connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js, node_modules/bson/ext/index.js

Comment: @Ashesh so what? we are not pushing it to the repo or will experience the issue next time. we are fixing a temporary bug in the environment in a temporary way, I think it's harmless.

Comment: I dont have a bson module under `node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules` folder despite installing mongoose, mongodb, bson...

Answer (score 36):

I have sorted the issue of getting the "Failed to load c++ bson extension" on raspbian(debian for raspberry) by:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

and then

```
npm update
```

Comment: I solved my problem just by running `npm update`, without even installing anything else.

Answer (score 27):

I was unable to solve this

until now. First of all you have to have system packages mentioned by Pradeep Mahdevu. Those are:

```
xcode-select --install (on a mac)
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential (on ubuntu)
```

Then I've installed node-gyp

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

like datadracer said but npm update also suggested by him is risky. It update all modules, which can be dangerous (sometimes API changes between versions).

I suggest going into **node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson** directory and from there use

```
node-gyp rebuild
```

That solved the problem for me.

Comment: What about windows :(

Comment: @JamieHutber Install VS 2013

Comment: I was doing this on a release of [DietPi](http://fuzon.co.uk/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=6) on a 512MB RP1. Just wanted to mentioned that I had to install **Python** (`apt-get install python`) and then from within `node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/` run `make`. This created `Release/bson.node`.

Answer (score 20):

A common problem is that node-gyp requires Python 2.x and if your system's `python` points to 3.x, it will fail to compile `bson`, without warning. You can fix this by setting a `python` global key in your npm config that points to the 2.x executable on your system. For example, on Arch Linux:

```
npm config -g set python "/usr/bin/python2"
```

Answer (score 19):

On WIN 8.1

It seems I used a wrong version of mongoose in my `package.json` file.

I removed the line `"mongoose" : "^3.8.15"` from `package.json`.

**CLI:**

```
npm install mongoose --save
```

Now it says `"mongoose": "^4.0.6"` in `package.json` and the error I had is gone.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me from countless hours of head bashing on the keyboard. This was the last and only solution that worked on windows. The issue was that I was running a version 3.x of mongoose which appeared to be incompatible with the latest mongodb install on my pc.

Comment: This finally got me running on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Yes, running on Mac as well . Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Following on Microsoft's "You’ve Got Documents! A MongoDB Jump Start" training session and had the same error, only related to the mongodb package - did the above steps for that one and sure enough, it's now running! :)

Answer (score 11):

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and to fix it for me I had to create a symlink for **node** to point to **nodejs** as described here:

[nodejs vs node on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Once I did that I re-ran these commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Comment: Great Anthony! I'm also running on Ubuntu 14.04 and your suggestion solved the problem for me. It is not enough to install build-essential and reinstall everything: I also had to add the 'node' ln.

Answer (score 8):

So in my case, I first tried to check under this directory */node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/*, just to confirm that I have the **bson** module.
I figured out that I did not have it in the first place, then I just run

```
npm install bson
```

and then

```
npm update
```

All got sorted.Tried and tested in Ubuntu.

Comment: worked for me as well, but I also typed `make` in `/devel/node_modules/bson/`

Comment: Worked for me. Cleaning the npm cache didn't. Actually, all I did was from /node_modules/mongoose ran `npm install bson`

Answer (score 8):

just wanted to say I also had the error

```
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

But with none of the other errors. I tried everything and turns out the mongodb drivers that I was specifying in the package.json file was incompatible with my version of MongoDB. I changed it to my latest version which was (1.4.34) and it worked!!!

Comment: indeed npm install mongodb@latest solved for me the problem

Answer (score 8):

`sudo npm rebuild` was what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8):

I finally corrected this error by updating my mongodb dependency version to **~2.0.36** in `package.json`.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "consolidate": "~0.9.1",
    "express": "3.x",
    "mongodb": "~2.0.36",
    "mongoose": "^4.1.12"
  }
```

Comment: Mine was slightly related, I was using mongod, and not mobgo**db**.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, All the above answers are only half right..
Took a long time to figure this out..

Mongoose bson install via npm throws warning and causes the error...

```
npm install -g node-gyp

git clone https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson.git
cd js-bson
npm install
node-gyp rebuild
```

This works like magic!!

Comment: This fails with error:
`$ node gyp rebuild
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/private/tmp/js-bson/gyp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:140:18)
    at node.js:1001:3`

Answer (score 4):

For me it only take to run these commands in my api directory:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean 
npm install
```

Answer (score 4):

I just ran:

```
sudo npm install bson
```

and

```
sudo npm update
```

and all become ok.

Comment: You should very much avoid running npm with sudo rights.

Comment: Anything that you can avoid having in the sudo space, you should. I don't think it'll cause any dire issues, it's just a good practice.

Here's an article that may help (can't vouch for it other than liking John Papa). http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/

Answer (score 3):

The bson extension message is just a **warning**, I get it all the time in my nodejs application.

**Things to check:**

- **MongoDB instance**: Do you have a MongoDB instance running?
- **Config**: Did you correctly configure Mongoose to your MongoDB instance? I suspect your config is wrong, because the error message spits out a very weird string for your mongodb server host name..

Comment: That was useful information. With that out of my way I figured out that I was mixing up the mongolab user account info with the actual mongodb user info for the database.

Comment: Hmm, i'm running into the same issue. Everything was working on my local test server though and I'm using mongoHQ so have no need for a local mongo instance, what else could be going wrong?

Comment: forget about that, Pradeep's answer below solved that :)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by changing line 10 of:

```
/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js
```

**from:**

```
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

**to:**

```
bson = require('bson');
```

Comment: That's making the package to use pure js solution, I guess

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I've understood that's avoiding exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem on CentOS by

- sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
- sudo npm install -g node-gyp
- rm -r node_modules
- npm cache clean
- npm install

Comment: @Theja said the error only happens on Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

I also got this problem and it caused my sessions not to work. But not to break either...

I used a mongoose connection.

I had this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(expressSession);
...
var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.use(bodyParser);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/TEST');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
  console.log('MongoDB connected');
});


app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: 'mysecret',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: null,
    expires: moment().utc().add('days',10).toDate(),// 10 dagen
  },
  store: new MongoStore({
  db: 'TEST',
  collection: 'sessions',
}),
```

Very straightforward. But req.session stayed always empty.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Did the trick. Watch out you dont have a 'mongodb' in your package.json! Just Mongoose and connect-mongo.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I fixed the problem on Ubuntu:

1. `ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`
2. `npm install node-gyp`
3. `cd node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson`
4. `node-gyp rebuild`

Inspired by @mbochynski answer, but I had to create a symbolic link first, otherwise the rebuild failed.

Answer (score 2):

i was having same trouble tried so many options but in the last `npm intall` in my mean app folder worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem because I was including the *node_modules* folder in my Git repository. When I rebuilt the *node_modules* on the other system it worked. One of them was running Linux, the other OS X. Maybe they had different processor architectures as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my EC2 instance.  I think the initial cause was because I had a Node instance running when I installed Mongo.  I stopped the Node service and then ran

```
sudo npm update
```

inside of the top level folder of my node project.  This fixed the problem and everything was just like new

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to run node on virtual machine (vagrant) shared folder. That was a problem. My host machine is Windows, installed node on Windows and worked like a charm. So if you are using virtual machine, just try to run node server on host machine.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and literally nothing worked for me. The error was showing `kerberos` is causing the problem and it was one of the `mongoose` dependencies. Since I'm on Ubuntu, I thought there might be permission issues somewhere between the globally installed packages -- in `/usr/lib/node_modules` via `sudo`, and those which are on the user space.

I installed `mongoose` globally -- with `sudo` of course, and everything began working as expected.

P.S. The `kerberos` package now also is installed globally next to `mongoose`, however I can't remember if I did it deliberately -- while I was trying to solve the problem, or if it was there from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on Docker with centOS 7, and encountered the same problem.

after looking around, and make several tries, I fixed this problem by installing mongodb, and mongodb-server

```
yum install mongodb mongodb-server
```

I don't think this is the best way to produce the minimal container. but I can limit the scope into the following packages

```
==============================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch              Version                          Repository          Size

==============================================================================================================
Installing:
 mongodb                          x86_64            2.6.5-2.el7                      epel                57 M
 mongodb-server                   x86_64            2.6.5-2.el7                      epel               8.7 M
Installing for dependencies:
 boost-filesystem                 x86_64            1.53.0-18.el7                    base                66 k
 boost-program-options            x86_64            1.53.0-18.el7                    base               154 k
 boost-system                     x86_64            1.53.0-18.el7                    base                38 k
 boost-thread                     x86_64            1.53.0-18.el7                    base                56 k
 gperftools-libs                  x86_64            2.1-1.el7                        epel               267 k
 libpcap                          x86_64            14:1.5.3-3.el7_0.1               updates            137 k
 libunwind                        x86_64            1.1-3.el7                        epel                61 k
 snappy                           x86_64            1.1.0-3.el7                      base                40 k
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7.1, these directions helped me to fix my build environment:

https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/58#issuecomment-68217275

http://christiankvalheim.com/post/diagnose_installation_problems/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve by uninstalling and reinstalling monk package. 
Initial install seemingly had a corrupt mongodb/bson dependency.

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 14.04 I needed to create a link in `/usr/bin` because `/usr/bin/env` was looking for `/usr/bin/node`.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

The error messages can be found in the `builderror.log` in each directory so for the message:

> bson@0.2.21 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson
>   (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

look at this file for more information about the exact problem:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/builderror.log`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing which helps me on Windows 7 (x64): https://stackoverflow.com/a/29714359/2670121

Reinstall node and python with x32 versions.
I spent a lot of time with this error:

> Failed to load c++ bson extension

and finally, when I installed module `node-gyp` (for building native addons) and even installed windows SDK with visual studio - nodejs didn't recognize assembled module `bson.node` as a module. After reinstalling the problem is gone.

Again, What does this error mean?

Actually, it's even not error. You still can use mongoose. But in this case, instead of fast native realization of `bson` module, you got `js-realization`, which is slower.

I saw many tips like: "edit path deep inside node_modules..." - which is totally useless, because it does not solve the problem, but just turned off the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I `npm install` all modules on my local machine (Mac), and I did not include `node_modules` in `.gitignore` and uploaded to github. Then I cloned the project to my aws, as you know, it is running Linux, so I got the errors. What I did is just include `node_modules` in `.gitignore`, and use `npm install` in my aws instance, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, the reason that the c++ version bson was not found was because we were behind a corporate proxy and something in the BSON build process needs to reach out to fetch files. When we looked in `node_modules/bson/builderror.log`, we saw an error like this:

```
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

Which suggested that the proxy might be the issue. Setting the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Followint @user1548357 I decided to change the module file itself. So as to avoid the problems pointed out by the valid comments below I included my changes in a postinstall script so that I can set it and forget it and be assured that it will run when my modules are installed.

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    // other scripts
    "postinstall": "node ./bson.fix.js"
},
```

and the script is:

```
// bson.fix.js
var fs = require('fs');
var file = './node_modules/bson/ext/index.js'
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  var result = data.replace(/\.\.\/build\/Release\/bson/g, 'bson');
  fs.writeFile(file, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
     console.log('Fixed bson module so as to use JS version');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

easily kick out the problem by just add this line both try and catch block
path: `node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js`

```
bson = require('bson');  instead 

bson = require('./win32/ia32/bson');
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

That is all!!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Please use formatting on code examples to make them easier for people to read.

Answer (score 0):

If the bson extension wasn't the reason, I guessed the other reason for "failed to connect" would be the user id's. So I created a new database and added a user for the database, with a password for that user (**note**: not mongolab account password).
I updated those on my code and voila! It worked. Duh right? :D

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem and I'm a Mac OSX user. Basically, you need to make sure you have installed the Xcode and also the "Command Line Tools" within the Xcode.

Xcode is free and can be downloaded over here:
https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

After you have installed the Xcode, open it and click "Preference" in the pull down menu, and click the "Downloads" icon. Make sure you have the "Command Line Tools" installed.

Then run the following commands like all the other users mentioned above:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```