# failed to load c++ bson

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to this whole Nodejs, MongoDB, mongoose world.  I'm just trying to follow some tutorials to get started and I keep getting this **"Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version"** error if I try and start any script with a reference to mongoose.

I've tried everything I can Google to fix it and nothing has worked including:

- Reinstalling build-essentials
- Reinstalling mongoDB
- Downgrading nodejs to 0.10.22
- deleting the node_modules dir
- cleaing the npm cache

I'm at a loss.  Can someone please help me out?  I just want to get back to the learning!

I'm running both nodejs and MongoDB on a Ubuntu 13 server.
This is my simple script.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    var UsersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String
    });
    var User = mongoose.model('User', UsersSchema);
    var user = new User({ name: "SomeName" })
    user.save();
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: It just means it either couldn't compile the native version or it wasn't available. It's falling back on a pure JS version. Is it crashing when you actually try to run your script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ubuntu 14.04 it may be related to this issue :

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/426

> there are two methods to solve this problem:
>
> upgrade gyp to the lastest version I found the --no-parallel option in
>   svn
>   source:[https://code.google.com/p/gyp/source/browse/trunk/pylib/gyp/**init**.py](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/source/browse/trunk/pylib/gyp/__init__.py)
>
> hack the node_gyp If you don't want upgrade your gyp, you can just
>   comment line 316
>   of/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js

```
 argv.push('-Dvisibility=default')
 argv.push('-Dnode_root_dir=' + nodeDir)
 argv.push('-Dmodule_root_dir=' + process.cwd())
 argv.push('--depth=.')
 //argv.push('--no-parallel')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem in initial setup  , fixed it by re installing build-essential package

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and then re install mongodb native driver also

```
npm install mongodb
```

The current version of node is v0.10.26. Try upgrading your node version also.

Comment: Opps!!  you have already tried this , after hitting enter i came to know . Why cant you try installing bson package only npm install bson