# Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
justhacker@justhacker-ThinkPad-Edge-E440:~/tools/codes/microblog$ node app.js 
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version 

/home/justhacker/tools/codes/microblog/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89       

throw new Error('Most middleware (like ' + name + ') is no longer bundle             ^ 

Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be 

installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.     

at Function.Object.defineProperty.get 

(/home/justhacker/tools/codes/microblog/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:89:13)     

at module.exports (/home/justhacker/tools/codes/microblog/node_modules/connect-

mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:30:22)     

at Object.<anonymous> (/home/justhacker/tools/codes/microblog/app.js:14:42)     

at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)     

at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)     

at Module.load (module.js:349:32)     

at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)     

at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)     

at startup (node.js:124:16)     

at node.js:807:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't have gcc/g++/make/python 2.x installed when you used npm to install the bson module. Try installing them first and then use npm to reinstall bson.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is caused by express changes in 4.0 version. Most of the included middlewares now come as "stand-alone" npm packages. You can read more about the changes [here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware).

About the `Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version.` error, you're probably missing python/gcc. 
You can read more about this error here: [node.js - Failed to load c++ bson extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension). If this don't fix your issue, try removing/reinstalling the driver/plugin.