# gcc not running even though it is installed

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, gruntjs, bson

I am having a very strange problem that I cannot figure out. When I try to run grunt on a project I am getting the following error message

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
App server started on port 3000
```

However everything that comes up in a search for that error message I have already done. I tried to run

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential
```

and I get a message saying it is already installed and the latest version...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
make is already the newest version.
gcc is already the newest version.
```

The application runs and everything but I can't figure out why I keep getting a message saying it cannot load c++ bson extension even though it is already installed and is the latest version. Anyone have any ideas? Please. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: some users resolved it reinstalling mongodb as well. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-mongodb-native/db4xD0x42eM

Comment: @Einacio Interesting idea. My mongodb install seems to be working ok though, I am able to load in users and such on the page from the mongodb. Doesn't rule out that that is the problem though, I'll look into updating the mongodb install and see if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to load c++ bson extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension)