# Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version when using monk to access Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

When I want to use monk as a middleware to access the mongodb, it prompts that

### Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

My running evn is the following:

1. OS X Yosemite
2. Node v0.10.32
3. npm 1.4.28
4. Mongodb 2.6.5
5. monk 0.9.1
   Does any of you know how to fix the issue?

Comment: Is something actually not working, or are you just concerned about the message?

Comment: Could be because make tools weren't available when you installed. Try looking at the solutions in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension)

Answer (score 3):

The Answer is in [Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651028/cannot-find-module-build-release-bson-code-module-not-found-js-bson)

Go the the monk index.js file (`yourProjectDirectory/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js`)

It should look like

```
try {
    // Load the precompiled win32 binary
    if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "x64") {
      bson = require('./win32/x64/bson');  
    } else if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "ia32") {
      bson = require('./win32/ia32/bson');  
    } else {
      bson = require('../build/Release/bson');  
    }   
} catch(err) {
    // Attempt to load the release bson version
    try {
        bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
    } catch (err) {
        console.dir(err)
        console.error("js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version");
        bson = require('../lib/bson/bson');
    }
}
```

Change the catch block to

```
try {
...
} catch(err) {
    // Attempt to load the release bson version
    try {
        bson = require('../browser_build/bson');
    } catch (err) {
        console.dir(err)
        console.error("js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version");
        bson = require('../lib/bson/bson');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

David