# Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows, node.js, mongodb

I am getting the below error:

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } 
  js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

Here are my version details:

- OS: Windows 7
- MongoDB: 2.6.5
- Node: 0.12.0

I have tried these things before I posted the issue here.

1. I went to `\node-modules\mongoose\node-modules\mongodb\node-modules\bson` folder and made below change in the binding-gyp file
   from `'include_dirs': [ '<!(node -e "require(\'nan\')")' ]`
   to 
   `'include_dirs': ["<!(nodejs -p -e \"require('path').dirname(require.resolve('nan'))\")"]`
2. Ran this command `npm install -g node-gyp`
3. I've updated the mongoose version to 3.8.21 inside `package.json`

Nothing works. Please suggest

Comment: I have tried below options suggested by you but no avail. I am getting below error                                                                                                                  { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

c:\raj\project\meandemo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:170
        throw new Error(msg);
              ^
Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<anonymous>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension/29368230#29368230

Comment: Please see this solution, hope it works! As C++ BSON extension is required for several other Modules too. 
Kindly note that, this solution is specific For Microsoft-OS Win-7
http://stackoverflow.com/a/29714359/4154706

Comment: Check the answers in this question too: [Failed to load c++ bson extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21656420/1494454)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load c++ bson extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension)

Answer (score 166):

Find in npm module mongodb:

> ..\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\ext\index.js

Change path to js version in catch block:

```
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

To:

```
bson = require('../browser_build/bson');
```

Or copy file in:

> ..\node_modules\bson\build\Release\bson

From:

> ..\node_modules\bson\browser_build\bson

Comment: I can not say for sure. Is likely to be working well. This is a bug file paths.

Comment: Awesome! Local environment though, so nothing tragic should happen anyway.

Comment: bson = require('../../../browser_build/bson.js');

Comment: Thank you. I needed to make a tweak in my case though, i didn't have a browser_build folder in bson_ext folder :  My problem was in "node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext\ext\index.js".  I changed the lines to "bson = require('../browser_build/bson');" AND copied the browser_build directory from "node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\bson" (2 folders up) to "node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\bson\node_modules\bson-ext"

Comment: This was helpful! I had this problem with a bson installation with mongojs

Comment: This is not a solution. With the same result you can just remove strings which prints error. This error appears because of native c++ plugin for bson not found and in this case js realization will be used anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is not native use. but this solution

Comment: it's a 32bit vs 64bit thing, the solution is to install 32bit NodeJs and Python on windows 7 64bit. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238424/error-in-npm-install-inspite-of-changing-the-file-bson/29714359#29714359

Comment: It's not 32/64 issue. I just installed with binary drivers using all 64 bit. See my comment below with @salihcenap reply.

Comment: still its not working for  me..i  m using latest version in node and mogodb

Comment: The error got changed to :    
TypeError: Cannot set property 'BSON_BINARY_SUBTYPE_DEFAULT' of undefined

Comment: @Alendorff True, but that is what most of us look for. I don't care about the C++ plugin, I want to get rid of the warnings because they break Node Inspector. From this perspective, your suggestion (removing error prints) is also a solution, because this shouldn't be an error, the code works fine with the JS fallback.

Comment: Sorry, downvoting as the second best answer here actually has the right, non-hack solution: Install a non-broken version of the package!

Comment: Replacing bson = require('../build/Release/bson'); to bson = require('../browser_build/bson');
worked for me.

Answer (score 71):

I had this issue today (Feb 19th, 2016) and I solved it just by installing the latest version of Mongoose. Try putting this in your package.json:

```
"mongoose": "~4.4"
```

Hope that helps. Solved it for me!

Comment: Worked for me.  I think its all a problem with an old mongoose version, which I had from following an old tutorial.  IMO this should be the correct answer.

Comment: Best answer, all the other ones about editing code within modules are hacks not solutions

Comment: Most straight forward solution without the need to mess with node_modules/mongodb etc. Thanks!

Comment: One of the best, just uninstall mongoose(npm uninstall mongoose) and reinstall it again(npm install mongoose)

Answer (score 18):

The problem is when you install mongoose via npm it assumes you have python installed on your windows and tries to build required libraries. Since you do not have python it skips building phase with a warning. But when you start your application, required modules are not there so you get this error.

In order to do things right first install python (version 2.7) on your computer from: https://www.python.org/downloads/ or if u have installed chockolatey just type `choco install python2`.

Then make sure your python variable is set. You can set it on command prompt like:

```
SET python=D:\Python27\python.exe
```

(Of course you should change the path according to your location of python)
Then install node-gyp:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

Now you can reinstall mongoose or whatever module causing the problem:

```
npm install mongoose
```

You will see some yellow lines instead of red ones this time but the error will be gone.

Comment: The python's version is important. node-gyp doesn't work with version > 3.0

Comment: This is not a full solution... I'm still getting the following error: MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".

Comment: @TheRebel It's assuming vs2010 toolchain. Add `--msvs-version=2012` or `2013e` depending on what you have installed. e.g. `npm install mongoose --msvs-version=2012`

Comment: what to do if i am deploying node app on heroku cloud.

Answer (score 15):

I resolved this issue by installing mogoose version `3.8.23`

```
npm install mongoose@3.8.23
```

Comment: worked here. is this an older version? why did it work?

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me. Search in your workspace for the text:

```
"../build/Release/bson"
```

You will probably find it inside the mongose and monk modules.

Then replace each:

```
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

with:

```
bson = require('bson');
```

that's all!

Comment: I was getting this error trying to run the default tests after setting up a project using meanjs. This fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try `npm install mongoose@3.8.23` and also replace 
`bson = require('../build/Release/bson');` to

`bson = require('../browser_build/bson');` in node_modules/bson/ext/index.js

Comment: Make sure the path to the bson.js is correct. For me  bson = require('../browser_build/bson.js');  worked.   Also check the version mongoose before going for the installation.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

Go to the file (in your project):

`node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js`

and change:

`bson = require('../build/Release/bson');`

to:

`bson = require('bson');`

Reference: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/118

Comment: How did you get this fix to persist? Did you check in your `node_modules` directory into source control?

Answer (score 7):

### Short answer

Install the latest version of mongodb.

### A little longer answer

Make sure your package.json is using the latest version of mongodb,
then remove node_modules/mongodb and do npm install again.
If you didn't use mongodb as a direct dependency, try to find which package is using mongdb. I used:

```
find . -type f -name package.json | xargs grep mongodb
...
./sails-mongo/package.json:    "mongodb": "1.4.26",
...
```

So I updated ./sails-mongo/package.json to:

```
"mongodb": "2.1.7",
```

Then remove node_modules/mongodb and do npm install again. Seems fine now.

### Even longer answer

I don't like the current suggested way of using

```
require('../browser_build/bson')
```

Since looking at ../browser_build/bson.js, a 4k+ lines file, which seem also a "non-native" implementation.  So although it won't spit out any  complains, it is still "using pure JS version", which means slower performance.

Looking at https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/145 and  https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/165, it seems like the issue was caused by:

> antoniofruci commented on Sep 15, 2015
>
> I just found out that c++ code has been moved out 6 months ago and it is now an optional dependency: bson-ext. Indeed, if you install latest version no error occurs.

So I tried to remove the whole node_modules and still got the same error. And looking at package.json of node_modules/mongodb, its version is still 1.4.26, not latest 2.1.7.

Apparently my mongodb comes as a dependency of another package I installed: sails-mongo.  Modifying the package.json of sails-mongo and redoing npm install finally solve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Deploying **Keystone JS CMS** I had same error and I think most elegant solution is this:

Install `npm-check-updates`:

```
root@keystonejs:~# npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Within your keystone site directory, where `package.json` is placed, check dependencies:

```
debian@keystonejs:~/myproject/manalcjim$ npm-check-updates -u
```

Then update all packages:

```
debian@keystonejs:~/myproject/manalcjim$ npm install
```

And finally if you chose `jade` for templates, maybe you will need install `jade` module explicitly:

```
debian@keystonejs:~/myproject/manalcjim$ npm install jade --save
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the bits that come with mongoose (`npm install mongoose`) have a working version of the `mongodb` package in its `node_modules` folder.

The following steps saved me the work of troubleshooting the issue:

- `npm install mongoose`
- copy `node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb` to my root `node_modules` folder (overwriting any version that came with `npm install mongodb`)
- ignore the `Failed to load c++ bson extension...` error (or change the code to be silent on the issue)

Answer (score 5):

The marked answer is completely wrong. All that does is hide the console log statement and does nothing whatsoever do address the actually issue. You can also close your eyes and it will achieve the same result.

The issue is caused by node-gyp and only that. Its purpose is to compile native extensions for certain modules such as bson.

If it fails to do so **then** the code will fallback to the JS version and kindly tell you so through the informative message:

```
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

I assume the question is really about how to compile the native C++ extension rather that just not seeing the message so let's address that.

In order for node-gyp to work your node-gyp must be up to date with your node and C++ compiler (that will differ based on your OS). Just as important your module must also be up to date.

First uninstall and reinstall node-gyp

```
npm un node-gyp -g;npm i node-gyp -g
```

Now you will need to fully uninstall and reinstall any node module in your app (that includes modules installed by requirements as well) that have bson. That should take care of the error. You can search for 'Release/bson' and find the culprits.

```
find node_modules/ -type 'f' -exec grep -H 'Release/bson' {} \;
```

And then uninstall and reinstall these modules.

Easier is to just redo the entire `node_modules` folder:

```
 rm -rf node_modules
 npm cache clear
 npm i
```

If you still experience issues then either 1) your module is out of date - check issue tracker in their repo or 2) you have a potential conflict - sometimes we may have a local node-gyp for example. You can run `node-gyp` by itself and verify versions.

Answer (score 5):

While creating setup for `www.spotdekho.com` in new `windows10` machine, I was unable to run command `"nodemon web.js"`  due same error

> "Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'"

Got it fixed by below steps :

> 1. Create folder "Release" inside "node_modules\bson\build\" location
> 2. Copy bson.js from "node_modules\bson\browser_build\"
> 3. Paste bson.js inside "node_modules\bson\build\Release" folder.

This will resolve the issue.

**PS : I am using mongoose version 4.8.8 .**

Thanks :) , hope it helps someone .

Answer (score 3):

When I was getting errors like this, I was upgrading from node v0.10 to node v4.x.x . What I had to do was install a newer version of gcc (I think I had gcc v4.4.x or something). I updated to gcc 4.7.2 and things worked after that.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same problem with bson.

trying a newer mongoose version

```
npm install mongoose@4.4
```

solved the issue.

Massimo.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command to uninstall mongoose `npm uninstall --save mongoose` - thereafter reinstall it but this time `npm` automatically installs the latest version of mongoose run `npm install --save mongoose` This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, All the above answers are only half right.. Took a long time to figure this out..

Mongoose bson install via npm throws warning and causes the error...

```
npm install -g node-gyp

git clone https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson.git
cd js-bson
npm install
node-gyp rebuild
```

This works like magic!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows 8.1, you might want to make sure that you are installing your npm modules with the correct visual studio compiler.

I have Visual Studio 2012 installed, this command works for me.
(after deleting node_modules dir)

**npm install --msvs_version=2012**

For some reason, node-gyp is trying to use the incorrect version of Visual Studio compiler.  I also noticed that the "npm install" command was printing out a warnings about not node-gyp dependencies when installing the mongodb and mongoose modules.

After using the correct msvs_version, the npm install warnings went away as well as the console warning when running my nodejs app.

You might also want to make sure that you have the correct Python 2.7.X version installed and not Python 3.0.X.

You will also need to make sure that python is in your env path.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio Community Edition 2013 using `npm install --msvs_version=2012`

Answer (score 2):

The only thing which helps me on Windows 7 (x64): https://stackoverflow.com/a/29714359/2670121

Reinstall node and python with x32 versions.
I spent many time with this error (Failed to load c++ bson extension) and finally, when I installed module `node-gyp` (for build native addons) and even installed windows SDK with visual studio - nodejs didn't recognize assembled module bson.node as module. After reinstall the problem is gone.

Again, What means this error?

Actually, it's even not error. You still can use mongoose. But in this case, instead of fast native realization of bson module, you got js-realization, which slower. I saw many tips like: "edit path deep inside node_modules..." - which totaly useless because it's not solve the problem but just turned off the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `npm install bson` and `npm update`

Answer (score 1):

You should never change files in NODE_MODULES library folder.

Those files are result of `npm install` command.

Basicaly, I think for Windows users - right way is use VM. It's what I'm doing when I work from home.

All you need:

`for CentOS: yum install gcc gcc-c++ make openssl-devel`

`for Debian/Ubuntu: apt-get install build-essential`

and then `npm install` or, if you have already done it - `npm update`

Comment: He says right in the question he is using Windows 7 - how does CentOS and Debian command help?

Comment: Oh, really, my bad. I didn't see that tag

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for me was to upgrade from node-mongodb 1.x to 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this thread is 1 year + old, but it helped me, albeit with a different module.

I installed mongoose-post-findv0.0.2 and this issue started. To fix it, I used the suggestions and navigated to \node_modules\mongoose-post-find\node_modules\bson\ext and opened the index.js file.

The file starts off with a try catch block trying to require the correct bson version

```
try {
    // Load the precompiled win32 binary
    if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "x64") {
      bson = require('./win32/x64/bson');  
    } else if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "ia32") {
      bson = require('./win32/ia32/bson');  
    } else {
      bson = require('../build/Release/bson');  
    }   
} catch(err) {
    // Attempt to load the release bson version
    try {
        bson = require('../browser_build/bson');
    } catch (err) {
        console.dir(err)
        console.error("js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version");
        bson = require('../lib/bson/bson');
    }
}
```

this is the corrected version. What was happening is it tried to load bson from ../build/Release/bson, couldn't find it and fell into the catch. There is tried to load bson again from ../build/Release/bson and of course failed. So I changes the path in the catch to look in ../browser_build/bson. This resolved the error.

I post this for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrade version of ubuntu to 16.04. I solved in this way, hope it helps.

```
$rm -rf node_modules
$npm --save install bson
$npm --save install mongoose
$npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case, the reason that the c++ version bson was not found was because we were behind a corporate proxy and something in the BSON build process needs to reach out to fetch files.  When we looked in node_modules/bson/builderror.log, we saw an error like this:

`gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)`

Which suggested that the proxy might be the issue.  Setting the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables solved it.

Sorry for reawakening comments on this, but I wanted to post this for anyone else that hits this in the future since this thread was very helpful in solving our issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with OS Windows 8.1 and I had the same problem. The source of the problem was the version of Python. I found the origin problem review the file ...\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos\builderror.log.

I installed the correct version of Python (2.7.9 for 64 bits) and it resolved my problem.

Note: The installed version of python must be equal or greater than 2.7.5 and less than 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Tried npm install mongoose --msvs_version=2012, if you have multiple Visual installed, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**First** copy `bson.js` code from `browser_build folder`

**second** create new file `bson.js` and paste code

**third** save the new file near to in `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried `bson = require('../browser_build/bson');` but end up running into another error

> Cannot set property 'BSON_BINARY_SUBTYPE_DEFAULT' of undefined

Finally I fixed this issue simply by `npm update`, this will fix the bson module in mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

So, i have the same problem and it happens then the specified mongoDB URL doesn't exist. So, to fix this you need to go "..\server\config\environment" folder and edit in "development.js" file the link to mongoDB.

Example:

```
// Development specific configuration
// ==================================
module.exports = {
  // MongoDB connection options
  mongo: {
    uri: 'mongodb://localhost/test2-dev'
  },

  seedDB: true
};
```

So, change this "uri: 'mongodb://localhost/test2-dev'" to some real path to your mongoDB database.

I will be glad if my post will help somebody...

Answer (score 0):

find in npm module mongodb ..node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\ext\index.js

and change path to js version in catch block

```
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

to    `bson = require('../browser_build/bson');`

```
try {
        // Load the precompiled win32 binary
        if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "x64") {
          bson = require('./win32/x64/bson');  
        } else if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "ia32") {
          bson = require('./win32/ia32/bson');  
        } else {
         bson = require('../browser_build/bson');  
        }   
    } catch(err) {
        // Attempt to load the release bson version
        try {
            bson = require('../browser_build/bson');
        } catch (err) {
            console.dir(err)
            console.error("js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version");
            bson = require('../lib/bson/bson');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For today (year 2017) we have that awesome npm module: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools
which usually solves lots of troubles with building of native things for windows.

Try to fix the issue with:

`Remove node_modules
npm install --global windows-build-tools
npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in mongo-sync version 4.1.2

but they made some changes and it is not working with the solutions provided here

the solution which worked for me

**Path** *node_modules/mongo-sync/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js*

Old Code

```
try {
    // Load the precompiled win32 binary
    if (process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "x64") {
        bson = require('./win32/x64/bson');
    } else if (process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "ia32") {
        bson = require('./win32/ia32/bson');
    } else {
        bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
    }
} catch (err) {
    // Attempt to load the release bson version
    try {
        bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
    } catch (err) {
        console.dir(err)
        console.error("js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version");
        bson = require('../lib/bson/bson');
    }
}
```

Change in the try block (copy the bson initialization from catch block)

```
bson = require('../lib/bson/bson');
```

So it will look like

```
try {
    // Load the precompiled win32 binary
    if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "x64") {
      bson = require('./win32/x64/bson');  
    } else if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "ia32") {
      bson = require('./win32/ia32/bson');  
    } else {
      bson = require('../build/Release/bson');  
    }   
} catch(err) {
    // Attempt to load the release bson version
    try {
        bson = require('../lib/bson/bson');
    } catch (err) {
        console.dir(err)
        console.error("js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version");
        bson = require('../lib/bson/bson');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I just find in npm module mongodb  the file index.js ..node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\ext\index.js

and change path to js version in catch block

bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
to  bson = require('../browser_build/bson');

but then I just changed it like this, all the similar... previously installed the module... : 
bson = require('bson');

Comment: Changing package codes under node_modules seems like a bad practice

Comment: yeah ... but it was necessary, in my case... perhaps that was a bug... nothing is perfect .... and that makes it much more fun

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem.

But I change my ***mongodb*** version to "**^2.2.33**" and no longer have the problem.

You shoud `npm rm` your old mongodb package on global or local and install this version.

If anyone don't want to have any side-effect on changing the direction name could try this method.

Answer (score -1):

For everyone still searching for a solution, I solved it by

```
bson = require('../../../browser_build/bson.js');
```

instead of

```
bson = require(../browser_build/bson.js');
```

so look if the path is correct.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this error by doing this and it perfectly worked for me. I have created a node App which has the folder node-android/node-modules.So here inside the node-modules directory I have one more directory bson/ext/index.js open this file and you can find inside the catch block.

```
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

change the above line to

```
bson = require('../browser_build/bson');
```

and the error was gone for me and the app is running perfectly without any errors or warnings.