# error in npm install inspite of changing the file Bson

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bson, monk

using mongodb3.0, node 0.12.0, npm 2.5.1 on windows 7 integrale, I am trying to read and write data into my database, but i have this error in npm intsall!

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

i tried to replace

```
bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
```

into

```
bson = require('../browser_build/bson');
```

but i had errors like this:

```
 exports.BSON.BSON_BINARY_SUBTYPE_DEFAULT = 0 TypeError: Cannot set property       'BSON_BINARY_SUBTYPE_DEFAULT' of undefined
```

i am using monk, anfd i have run npm mongodb, npm monk

Comment: Does the code run anyway with the first error? I've received that error too, but it hasn't affected the code.

Comment: sure it doesn't affect rest of your code but it is really unpleasant. In my case everything used to work until i run npm update

Answer (score 6):

**Problem:** Modules like Mongo-DB, Socket.io and other requires [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) to compile C/C++ code which Kim also discussed. MSVC++ comes only for 32-bit OS, **NOW** this is the real problem because if you've install node.js and the other requirments like [Python 2.7.3](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3#download) with the 64-bit versions, then you'll face the problems like I did.

Follow these steps:

- Uninstall Node.js
- Uninstall all the Modules including Python
- Now Install 32-bit versions of all the above uninstalled applications and platforms.
- Follow all the necessary steps.
- Now install modules you want to use.

You may see some errors while installing, but don't panic. Try running your application and it will work just fine.

**NOTE:** This solution is platform specific i.e. for MS Windows.

Comment: This is the only thing that helps me. I spent about 4h with dancing around this problem. Finaly, the problem was with the node (0.12.3 x64) which didn't recognize bson.node as a module. When I reinstall all this stuff (node, python) with x32 versions, the problem is gone.

Comment: I had this problem for 2 days. And after a lot of research I found this solution here on stackoverflow. But it was not explained in detail. So I chose to post this answer.
Good luck. (y)

Comment: i suspect the lastest version of node coz everything did work well until i run npm update in my x64 node

Comment: @MarcelDjaman were you using Modules like mongoDB, socket.io with x64 node and were they working fine??

Comment: everything works fine expect some little nasty warning messages like js-bon failed to load c++ bson extension...

Comment: I have the same warning messages but neither my modules like mongo or socket.io were working nor was my application until I followed those steps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm on windows 8.1, but what I did, was first install python 2.7.9 and also visual studio community edition. Both are needed to compile bson. Then I installed: "npm install -g node-gyp", after that I just deleted the node_modules from my project and did "npm install" again. Solved. When I did the install again I could see the message on the console that said bson was compiling.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB depends on a few libraries. At some point you would have done:

```
npm install mongodb --save
```

One of these dependencies is [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) which is needed to compile bson. Importantly, node-gyp requires Python 2.7 and Microsoft Visual Studio to be installed (see [installation section of node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp)). If you don't have Python 2.7 and Visual Studio, then node-gyp will fail to build which means it can't compile bson (causing the initial error).

Navigate to: **node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\bson**

You should find the *builderror.log* file with more information about why node-gyp failed to build. Most likely this will be due to Python 2.7 or Visual Studio not being installed.

**Here's what I had to do to fix it:**

I had the exact same problem as you with the bson module not found error. I also changed the `require` line as you did and ended up with the same error (exports.BSON...). I then uninstalled monk and mongodb:

```
npm uninstall mongodb --save
npm uninstall monk --save
```

Installed Python 2.7 and Microsoft Visual Studio, then installed mongodb and monk again:

```
npm install mongodb --save
npm install monk --save
```

This fixed it.

Comment: I find bson in the same pathin the directory mongoose, is that ok?

Comment: It stills have the same error! I tried to run node-gyp rebuild but i have this error :     `gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Node\test) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed when i changed the version of node 10.34 and nom 1.4.28