# js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version on mongoose in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-webkit

I'm trying create a desktop system using `node-webkit`, and using `mongoose` for handle my `MongoDB`

When I calling `require('mongoose')` function, this will return fallowing error, and nothing is happen in database:

```
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

I tried create my database handle functions in a external `test.js` file, contain `var mongoose = require('mongoose')`, and execute it with `node test.js` in terminal, this is execute success, saved in database, returned insert row data.

Why this problem occur only is executed with `node-webkit`? How to can I fix this problem?

My environment is Windows 7, 64 bits

---

Posts where I tried:

1. [content="Problem with Mongoose/MongoJS on node-webkit 0.7.5 - Windows 7](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1174)
2. [Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651028/cannot-find-module-build-release-bson-code-module-not-found-js-bson)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's#bson = require('../build/Release/bson');#bson = require('../../../browser_build/bson');#g' node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/index.js
```

From root catalog.
Or find and correct that paths manually