# 'nodemon' generates a bson error

Tags: node.js, npm

```
ogrotten:~/workspace/beekly $ nodemon app.js
[nodemon] 1.8.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

This is a tutorial app that works fine with `npm start`.

I did `npm i bson` then `npm update` both local and global with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution in stackoverflow link below. This may work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28932441/5445482