# kadirahq/meteor-up - mup deployment issue

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

When trying to deploy meteor app to azure using kadirahq/meteor-up, i am getting the following error

```
x Verifying Deployment: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
> node npm-rebuild.js


> bcrypt@0.8.7 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
make: Leaving directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
bcrypt@0.8.7 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
bindings@1.2.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bindings
nan@2.3.5 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/nan

=> Redeploying previous version of the app

-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=100'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On mup logs --tail=50, the following logs are displayed:

```
[52.187.xx.xxx]read-package-tree@5.1.5 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-tree
[52.187.xx.xxx]realize-package-specifier@3.0.3 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/realize-package-specifier
[52.187.xx.xxx]retry@0.9.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/retry
[52.187.xx.xxx]sha@2.0.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha
[52.187.xx.xxx]sorted-object@2.0.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sorted-object
[52.187.xx.xxx]text-table@0.2.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/text-table
[52.187.xx.xxx]uid-number@0.0.6 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number
[52.187.xx.xxx]umask@1.1.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/umask
[52.187.xx.xxx]unique-filename@1.1.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/unique-filename
[52.187.xx.xxx]unique-slug@2.0.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/unique-filename/node_modules/unique-slug
[52.187.xx.xxx]unpipe@1.0.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/unpipe
[52.187.xx.xxx]write-file-atomic@1.1.4 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/npm/node_modules/write-file-atomic
[52.187.xx.xxx]oauth-sign@0.8.2 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/oauth-sign
[52.187.xx.xxx]pubsub-js@1.5.3 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/pubsub-js
[52.187.xx.xxx]qs@6.1.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/qs
[52.187.xx.xxx]request@2.72.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/request
[52.187.xx.xxx]stringstream@0.0.5 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/stringstream
[52.187.xx.xxx]tough-cookie@2.2.2 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/tough-cookie
[52.187.xx.xxx]tunnel-agent@0.4.3 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/tunnel-agent
[52.187.xx.xxx]selectn@0.9.6 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/selectn
[52.187.xx.xxx]simple-mock@0.7.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/simple-mock
[52.187.xx.xxx]sinon@1.17.5 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sinon
[52.187.xx.xxx]util@0.10.3 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/util
[52.187.xx.xxx]soap@0.9.5 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/soap
[52.187.xx.xxx]lodash@2.4.2 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/soap/node_modules/lodash
[52.187.xx.xxx]strip-bom@0.3.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/strip-bom
[52.187.xx.xxx]tweetnacl@0.13.3 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/tweetnacl
[52.187.xx.xxx]xml2js@0.4.16 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/xml2js
[52.187.xx.xxx]xmlbuilder@4.2.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/xmlbuilder
[52.187.xx.xxx]lodash@4.13.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/lodash
[52.187.xx.xxx]xmlhttprequest@1.8.0 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/xmlhttprequest
[52.187.xx.xxx]{
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "meteor-dev-bundle": "0.0.0",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "npm": "3.10.5",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "ares": "1.10.1-DEV",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "http_parser": "2.5.2",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "icu": "56.1",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "modules": "46",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "node": "4.4.7",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "openssl": "1.0.2h",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "uv": "1.8.0",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "v8": "4.5.103.36",
[52.187.xx.xxx]  "zlib": "1.2.8"
[52.187.xx.xxx]}
[52.187.xx.xxx]npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
[52.187.xx.xxx]npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
[52.187.xx.xxx]npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
[52.187.xx.xxx]=> Starting meteor app on port:80
[52.187.xx.xxx]{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
[52.187.xx.xxx]js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
[52.187.xx.xxx]/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
[52.187.xx.xxx]                     throw(ex);
[52.187.xx.xxx]                     ^
[52.187.xx.xxx]MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:9001] on first connect
[52.187.xx.xxx]    at Object.Future.wait (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15)
```

My app should run in port 4010 and the following is the mup.js file that i am using for mup deploy:

```
module.exports = {
    servers: {
        one: {
            host: '52.187.xx.xxx',
            username: 'myusername',
            password: 'mypassword',
            env: {
                PORT: 4010
            }
        }
    },

    meteor: {
        name: 'myapp',
        path: '../../../src',
        servers: {
            one: {}
        },
        buildOptions: {
            serverOnly: true,
            debug: false
        },
        env: {
            ROOT_URL: 'http://52.187.xx.xxx',
            MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost:4011/meteor',
            PORT: 4010
        },
        dockerImage: 'abernix/meteord:base',
        deployCheckWaitTime: 900
    },

    mongo: {
        oplog: true,
        port: 27017,
        servers: {
            one: {}
        }
    }
};
```

Can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try reading more line (more than 50). I too faced a similar issue and the issue was in last 100 lines or so.

Comment: thanks @Ankit, i had update my question.

Comment: This seems to be a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651028/cannot-find-module-build-release-bson-code-module-not-found-js-bson

Comment: @Jeremiah, i'm having the "Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson']" error even on my local but the app works fine.