# Auth0 custom database mongodb, signup script is returning SandboxTimeoutError

Tags: mongodb, auth0

I'm trying to use my own mongo database which is created in [mlab](https://mlab.com/) in [auth0](https://auth0.com/) for user management. Here is the template they provided.

```
function create (user, callback) {
  mongo('mongodb://user:pass@mymongoserver.com/my-db', function (db) {
    var users = db.collection('users');

    users.findOne({ email: user.email }, function (err, withSameMail) {

      if (err) return callback(err);
      if (withSameMail) return callback(new Error('the user already exists'));

      bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) { return callback(err); }
        user.password = hash;
        users.insert(user, function (err, inserted) {
          if (err) return callback(err);
          callback(null);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

After changing connection URI, I tried to "create" a user by providing email and password with the script. I see the following error:

```
[SandboxTimeoutError] Script execution did not complete within 20 seconds. Are you calling the callback function?
```

I followed the Debug Script they provided. Here is the log:

```
$ wt logs -p "myservice-eu-logs"
[12:35:27.137Z]  INFO wt: connected to streaming logs (container=myservice)
[12:35:29.993Z]  INFO wt: new webtask request 1478435731301.992259
[12:35:30.047Z]  INFO wt: { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
[12:35:30.047Z]  INFO wt: js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
[12:36:05.080Z]  INFO wt: finished webtask request 1478435731301.992259 with HTTP 500 in 35096ms
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: looks like your missing some external file/module?

Comment: A similar issue is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651028/cannot-find-module-build-release-bson-code-module-not-found-js-bson) for Node. However, I don't have any idea where I can access `bson` variable in Auth0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `bcrypt.hashSync` is a synchronous method, so the callback function is never called and the script times out.

Either use:

`var hashedPwd = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password);`

or

`bcrypt.hash(user.password,10,function(....);`

Comment: Great. I replaced `bcrypt.hashSync` call with `bcrypt.hash` This resolved the issue. Thanks a lot.