# js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension ,using pure JS version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm developing an app with express.js and mongodb. I'm getting above mentioned error when i run my app. I'm using windows 8 as developing platform.. How can i get rid of it?

Comment: I found a similar question here [Failed to load c++ bson extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension). I also think (just like in that question) you should post the whole error log.

Comment: though this error is shown in your console, the application will work ...

Comment: @llkin 
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Comment: @PiyasDe No , it's not working at all.