# Node-oracle sometimes return no result

Tags: node.js, oracle, random

I'm using **NodeJS v0.10.38** with **node-oracle Driver  "oracle": "^0.3.7"** (https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle) connected to **oracle 11G database** thought OCI driver.

```
export OCI_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/instantclient_11_2/
export OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/instantclient_11_2/sdk/include
export OCI_VERSION=11 # Integer. Optional, defaults to '11'
export NLS_LANG=.UTF8 # Optional, but required to support international characters
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$OCI_LIB_DIR
```

**Everything is install and ok**.

When runing node I only have one error :

```
[Error:  
/home/pocho/ZaRaSoFt/node_modules/mongojs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson    /build/Release/bson.node: invalid ELF header]
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

On executing oracle query, **some queries return no results on random**.
Further tries of the same queries may return results.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure but I think there are unresolved dependencies such as cpp extenstions.

I would recommend open solution in visual studio and it should download the cpp extensions.