# JXCore packaging, NPM errors

Tags: node.js, npm, jxcore

When I compile code with

> \> jx package bin/www.js myApp
>   \> packaging...
>   \> [OK] compiled file is ready (myApp.jx)

it successfully created myApp.jx and myApp.jxp
But when I executed command

> \> jx myApp.jx
>   
> It gives errors as:
>
> C:\**\node_modules\express-session\node_modules\debug***node.js.jx***:72
>   exports.formatters.o = function(v) {
>                        ^
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'o' of undefined
>       at Object. (C:\**\node_modules\express-session\node_modules\debug\node.js.jx:72:22)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:519:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..jx (module.js:1604:7)
>       at Module.load (module.js:346:36)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:378:17)
>       at require (module.js:396:17)
>       at Object. (C:\**\node_modules\express-session***index.js.jx:17:13***)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:519:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..jx (module.js:1604:7)
>       at Module.load (module.js:346:36)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:378:17)
>       at require (module.js:396:17)
>       at Object. (C:\*****server.js.jx***:7:15)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:519:26)

Comment: does the app work unpacked (`jx bin/www.js`) ?. Also, did you see any warnings (about native files) during package creation?

Comment: works with jx bin/www.js

Comment: with errors as > { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

Comment: So the same error, huh? Then you can check if the same works with node. Because if it isn't - that not a JXcore issue.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it may be npm module issues.

Comment: can you provide me some solutions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think,the problem is with NPM, step by step compile each of the .js file, and introduce required NPM package one by one , you will get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not a JXcore issue (the app fails with node too), you might want to seek the problem related with `js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version`.

For example I saw this answer: [Failed to load c++ bson extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension), and they say it could be fixed by reinstalling modules with `npm install`.

Comment: index.js.jx: ,   node.js.jx  , server.js.jx. These files are in error log, I compiled them, but it gets failed