# Error accessing mongodb from node: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Just installed Mongo, mongodb driver and node. All current stable versions on a Ubuntu 14.04

```
mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
node --version
v5.2.0
```

I'm pretty new to koa/mongo/node so I clone some github repos, but when I run code I always get this error:

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

Similar erros on stackoverflow are for older versions and there was either not clear solution or not working in my case.

How is the workflow? What is this extension for?

I tried reinstalling build-essential and node-gyp but without knowing the reason. Maybe is related to the monk or mongoose version if the projects are "old"?

Comment: Have you tried some solutions in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing some build tools on your system.
In that case mongo driver will fallback to using a Javascript version of the bson parser, which is fine for development, but probably not in production.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
cp ProjectDirectory/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/browser_build/bson.js ProjectDirectory/node_modules/monk/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build/Release
```

I think you can use also move, I never tried.
The error message tell you bson.js is missing in "../build/Release folder", so you only have to put the file in the right place