# node.js tutorial failing because of missing bson module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bson, monk

**Background Information**

I'm trying to follow this tutorial :
http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/

I have a mongo database running on another linux box...and fwiw, I know it's working because I have a php application that can connect and query.

I'm not using mongoose... but monk, since this is what the tutorial calls for.

Here's what my package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "mongodb": "^1.4.4",
    "monk": "^1.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta4",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

~

**Problem**

When I try to run the test node application, I'm getting the following error message:

```
me@mydevbox:/var/www/html/node/testapp$ node app.js 
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/node/testapp/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

This is what the index.js file looks like:

```
  3 try {
  4         // Load the precompiled win32 binary
  5         if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "x64") {
  6           bson = require('./win32/x64/bson');  
  7         } else if(process.platform == "win32" && process.arch == "ia32") {
  8           bson = require('./win32/ia32/bson');
  9         } else { 
 10           bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
 11         }     
 12 } catch(err) {
 13         // Attempt to load the release bson version
 14         try {
 15                 bson = require('../build/Release/bson');
 16         } catch (err) {
 17                 console.dir(err)
 18                 console.error("js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version");
 19                 bson = require('../lib/bson/bson');
 20         }
 21 }
```

**What I've Tried:**

Based on other posts on stackoverflow.com, I tried to change line 15 to look like this:

```
15                 bson = require('bson');
```

I've also tried running the command:

```
 sudo npm install bson
```

But that didn't resolve the problem.

In case it helps, I did a search for "bson" on my box and came up with these results:  http://pastebin.com/WKQygGak

**System Information**

Ubuntu 15.10

**EDIT 1**

```
me@mydevbox:/var/www/html/node/testapp$ sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
gcc is already the newest version.
make is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And then I ran the following commands:

http://pastebin.com/MDerppWB

There's seems to have been an error on line 10 but I'm not sure how to correct it.

**EDIT 2**

This is what I currently have in my npm config:

```
me@mydevbox:/var/www/html/node/testapp$ npm config list
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/3.10.3 node/v6.3.1 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/me/.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://10.1.1.11:8080/"
proxy = "http://10.1.1.11:8080/"
python = "python2.7"

; globalconfig /usr/etc/npmrc

; node bin location = /usr/bin/nodejs
; cwd = /var/www/html/node/testapp
; HOME = /home/me
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

me@mydevbox:/var/www/html/node/testapp$
```

Also as a test I tried to just to "sudo npm install bson" and it fails with the same errors that I see in the pastebin I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need build essentials, because there is some c++ dependency going on here. Please refer to the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22054632/3199310) or just do the following.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential

rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Edit:

This could also be a python issue. Make sure python 2.7 is installed for ubuntu, in your PATH, and then set up npm to look for python:

```
npm config set python python2.7
```

[Others](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2285) having the same issue as you found this to be a solution. Python looks to be the next step since you've established that you have build-essentials.

Edit 2:

Side note.. I know you're following a tutorial.. but for future reference I strongly recommend using the [native mongo driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/#node-js-driver). It's faster than ORM's like mongoose, and not difficult to use (not saying mongoose is difficult to use, but just not as flexible or performant).

Comment: Hi. Please see EDIT 1 for the detailed results of your answer

Comment: hey again.  yeah... i had already tried that before... I've posted my config for you.  Please see EDIT 2.

Comment: @Happydevdays is python in your path? You can use path in terminal by typing python?

Comment: i think it is because I can just type "python" from anywhere on my command line and it triggers python 2.7.