# How do I locate my user path to Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Examples of what I'm getting in my Terminal:

```
$ cd portfolio
-bash: cd: portfolio: No such file or directory

$ meteor create myApp
-bash: meteor: command not found

$ sudo meteor create myApp
Password:
sudo: meteor: command not found

$ meteor help
-bash: meteor: command not found
```

I have multiple apps that were all running until a few minutes ago. Total noob so I probably did something stupid. But... Thought I might uninstall and do a fresh install, but can't do anything on the Command-Line.

Mac OS 10.11.16

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Update: I ran curl https://install.meteor.com/. At least something happened. What I got is:

```
Couldn't write the launcher script. Please either:
  (1) Run the following as root:
        cp "$LAUNCHER" /usr/bin/meteor
  (2) Add "\$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
  (3) Rerun this command to try again.

Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
docs.meteor.com.
EOF
  fi
else
  cat <<EOF

Now you need to do one of the following:

  (1) Add "\$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
  (2) Run this command as root:
        cp "$LAUNCHER" /usr/bin/meteor
```

I don't know how to implement these instructions...!!! If anyone can please walk me thru it.

Comment: `curl https://install.meteor.com/` doesn't do anything. Did you run `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`? Did it prompt for your password? (it should)

Comment: Hi Christian. Wasn't prompted for a password, but seems to have run the install script? If you look at my original post, I edited it to include where I am after running curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh and how I'm stuck, again. Thank you.

Comment: well your post doesn't include the `| sh`, therefore my question. If you were not prompted for your password then something probably went wrong. Have you tried to rerun the script?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I ran l sh after I originally posted. I ran it again as you suggested and this time it did ask me for my password.

Comment: I get all this again. Which I was trying to fix. Which was what got me in trouble. Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
In order to use the native implementation instead, run
 meteor npm install --save bcrypt
in the root directory of your application.
[Error: Module did not self-register.]
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Comment: And thank you. You got me up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

So now you can run `meteor npm install --save bcrypt` as your terminal said and then it should work.

Comment: Thanks Jim! That eliminated all the errors. All I have left is js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version. Whatever that means...

Comment: Try to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension) please.

Comment: Thanks for the link!