# Error This version of node/NAN/v8 requires a C++11 compiler

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I've recently upgraded Nodejs from 0.13 to 6.9 and I started getting some errors when running my nodejs app, I googled around, managed to fix some errors and new ones appeared, I ended up deleting the `node_modules` folder of my app, clearing npm's cache and running the npm install again and this is where I am stuck, you can see the full output in this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KVDk7JN6).

More details:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Nodejs v6.9.1 (both `node --version` and `nodejs --version` return the same)
- node-gyp, clang, gcc, make and build-essential are all installed

Node modules my app uses:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "~1.2.1",
    "kurento-client": "Kurento/kurento-client-js",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.23",
    "dateformat": "~1.0.11",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3"
  }
```

I've been trying the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656420/failed-to-load-c-bson-extension) to no avail.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally solved this, I'll leave the solution here for whomever runs into the same problem.

Here's what the problem was, Unbuntu 12.04 only has `gcc` 4.6.3 in the official repository, but C++11 is only supported from 4.8.1, therefore you need to install 4.8 from a different PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50
```

Now this alone did not fix the problem since it seems `node-gyp` uses `g++` instead of `gcc` so just do the same for `g++`:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 50
```

after that `sudo npm install` should run without problems.

Comment: Gooooooooooooooooood! You saved my day!

Comment: Absolute legend

Comment: I had to run the following to complete the gcc installation:

`sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`
`sudo update-alternatives --config g++`