# Image uploading failed using AFNetworking 2.6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

When I trying to upload image using AFNetworking 2.6.0 get error on server side like

> Failed to load C++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22054632/3901620

Comment: Is there any changes that should be changed on app side code?

Comment: no .. you dont ..

Comment: Ok. But I am also getting "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
   at ServerResponse.setHeader"  this error with above. Please can you help me in this?