# After installation of Gulp: “no command 'gulp' found”

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

After installing [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) via npm, I receive a `no command 'gulp' found` error when running the `gulp` command from the same directory it was installed into.

When looking under the `node_modules/.bin/` directory, I can see the `gulp` executable there.

Is there something wrong with my npm installation?

Comment: did you do a global install? `npm install gulp -g`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I did a global install and still nothing...

Comment: This link will surely help you out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707907/5222115

Answer (score 527, accepted):

That's perfectly normal.
If you want `gulp-cli` available on the command line, you need to install it globally.

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

See [the install instruction](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started/1-quick-start.md).

Also, `node_modules/.bin/` isn't in your `$PATH`. But it is automatically added by npm when running npm scripts (see [this blog post for reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20161013005003/http://substack.net/task_automation_with_npm_run)).

So you could add `scripts` to your `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "your-app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "gulp": "gulp",
        "minify": "gulp minify"
    }
}
```

You could then run `npm run gulp` or `npm run minify` to launch gulp tasks.

Comment: I am asked to run npm install -g gulp as sudo (Root . Admin) but if I do that then when I am exiting to normal user it cant find gulp command.

I dont think its good to stay in root for everything I'd rather get my environment properly working.
So anyone know what could cause this issue pls..

Comment: I guess it all depends on how/where node was installed. When using https://github.com/creationix/nvm, you don't need to be root to install global libs.

Comment: I think i used the installer on mac OSX to install nodejs.org I dont know the difference between nodejs and node @£$@

Comment: Please keep in mind that gulp itself is no longer a global package. Instead, global-cli is (npm -i -g gulp-cli) and that global gulp should actually be uninstalled first!

Answer (score 14):

I solved the issue without reinstalling node using the commands below:

```
$ npm uninstall --global gulp gulp-cli
$ rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/gulp.1
$ npm install --global gulp-cli
```

Comment: A slightly updated version of this worked for me, as I use NVM to manage my Node environment:
`$ npm uninstall -g gulp gulp-cli` `$ rm /Users/[usrName]/.nvm/versions/node/[nodeVersion]/share/man/man1/gulp.1` `$ npm install -g gulp-cli`

Comment: Global is a bad idea.

Answer (score 13):

I actually have the same issue.

This link is probably my best guess:

[nodejs vs node on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04)

I did that to resolve my problem:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node 
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs 
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: You also need `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` since so many apps/packages look for it there.

Comment: The `ln -s [target] [name|directory]` command creates a symbolic link ("alias" or "shortcut"). See http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ln1.html

Comment: still not working here... Man, I kinda think that this is trivial. But this link from another SO page got the right answer. Just run it locally http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457377/nodejs-gulp-not-found-after-npm-install?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8):

I solved the issue removing gulp and installing gulp-cli again:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/gulp
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

Comment: Also needed to use `sudo`

Comment: needed to use sudo, but this finally worked

Answer (score 4):

if still not resolved try adding this to your `package.js` scripts

`"scripts": { "gulp": "gulp" },`

and run `npm run gulp`
it will runt gulp scripts from gulpfile.js

Answer (score 2):

Installing on a Mac - Sierra - After numerous failed attempts to install and run gulp globally via the command line using several different instructions I found I added this to my path and it worked:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.6.0/libexec/npm/bin/:$PATH
```

I got that path from the text output when installing gulp.

Answer (score 2):

Tried with sudo and it worked !!

```
sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
```

Comment: Please learn what `--global` means and how this doesn't fix the problem on other peoples computers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on lubuntu 19.10

I've used combination of previous answers, and didn't tweak the `$PATH`.

1. `npm uninstall --global gulp gulp-cli`
   This removes any package if they are already there.
2. `sudo npm install --global gulp-cli` Reinstall it as root user.

If you want to do copy and paste

```
npm uninstall --global gulp gulp-cli && sudo npm install --global gulp-cli
```

should work

I guess `--global` is unnecessary here as it's installed using `sudo`, but I've used it just in case.

Answer (score 1):

in my case there was only on issue, just  put "gulp":"gulp" in the script portion, of package.json, and then use command npm run gulp.