# Locally installed gulp not running in command line?

Tags: node.js, command-line, gulp, package.json

I am new to nodejs and gulp stuff. I working on a nodejs project in which I have to run jslint on all the files. I am using gulp for this purpose.

My problem is that In order to run gulp on cli I don't want to install gulp globally and also does not want to update my path variable, So I have installed gulp and other node modules in my project locally using the package.json file

> cd myproject
>
> npm install

Since I don't want to install gulp globally and want to run the local gulp I have added script in my package.json file like this as given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115400/why-do-we-need-to-install-gulp-globally-and-locally) question

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "1.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-jslint": "^0.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
      "gulp": "./node_modules/.bin/gulp"   // is this correct?
    }
}
```

Add added a gulpfile.js inside my myproject folder

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// include plug-ins
var jslint = require('gulp-jslint');

// JS hint task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
  gulp.src('./common/srp/*.js')
    .pipe(jslint())
    .pipe(jslint.reporter('default'));
});

gulp.task("default", ["lint"]);
```

But now on my command line inside myproject folder, when I run gulp and gulp lint I get an error

> user1-VirtualBox:~/myproject$ gulp lint
>
> /usr/local/node-v0.10.26-linux-x64/bin/gulp   No such file or
>   directory

Its looking for gulp in the global node module.

Is there a way to make gulp run on cli without installing globally and updating PATH variable.

Any help will be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Try remove scripts in your package.json

Comment: @mydo47 script is added because its was one way of using locally installed gulp.

Comment: when you run `npm install`. Gulp installed in your local folder.

Answer (score 39):

You can find any executable installed by npm in `node_modules/.bin`. So you can run gulp locally using:

```
./node_modules/.bin/gulp
```

You can find more information at [no command 'gulp' found - after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224831/no-command-gulp-found-after-installation)

Comment: There is only one `gulp.js` in `bin` folder.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy it's .bin

Comment: but i got `Local gulp not found in` when executing `.\scripts\node_modules\.bin\gulp`, why?

Comment: Are you sure you installed `gulp`? Are there other binaries in `.\scripts\node_modules\.bin`? Is `scripts` your repo?

Comment: After installing gulp locally `node_modules\.bin\gulp` didn't exist. Running `npm link gulp` worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

With your code you should be able to run command
npm run gulp

Please try

One way to define script is

```
"scripts": {
      "gulp": "gulp"
    }
```

If in case you are not able to run gulp command in your project, run

```
npm link gulp
```

It will link your global install gulp with your local project. Then try

```
 gulp -v
```

If it is showing you the version then you are done. Now you can run any gulp command as you want.

Comment: `npm link gulp` proper answer

Comment: `npm run gulp` was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Scripts defined in `package.json` are accessed through NPM, i.e. `npm run-script gulp`. I imagine you're trying to run plain old `gulp`, which *should* fail since you didn't install it globally.

The scripts section won't automatically create an alias, which I think is your mistake here. You could define one yourself or create a simple bash script if you don't want to type it every time.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
path_to_node path_to_gulp_js gulp_task
```

Example:

```
node\node.exe node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js build
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @snorberhuis said. The only way for me to get gulp to work globally was to call gulp manually
I am building in a Jenkins environment

**Execute Windows Batch Command**

```
cd your-app
npm install gulp
```

**Execute Windows Batch Command**

```
cd your-app\node_modules\.bin 
gulp
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another alternative that will work locally but will give you global like feeling.
Add to your shell config i.e. `~/.bash_profile` the following

`export PATH=$PATH:./node_modules/.bin`

you have to `source` that file, execute `rehash` or just open a new shell and then `gulp` (and any other script inside that folder) shall be available as a global command.

Answer (score 1):

The way I did this after bashing my head every possible place is simply going to your Application and install npm dependencies like this:

1- `E:\webra-jenkins\Code\trunk\WebRa.Web>npm install`

Once npm installed then go this directory

2- `[%Application_path%]\node_modules\.bin`

And execute the gulp and give your file/task, like this:

3-`[%Application_path%]\node_modules\.bin>gulp gulpfile --tasks`

In my case as I saw the following lines... I got the inner happiness

```
18:06:36] Working directory changed to [%Application_path%]
[18:06:37] Tasks for [%Application_path%]\gulpfile.js
```

Now you can run your tasks 1 by one.

```
[%Application_path%]\node_modules\.bin>gulp pack-vendor-js
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your project `node_modules/.bin` folder and make sure gulp is in there. I had a case where it wasn't there that I never tracked down the reason for. If it isn't there, try re-installing gulp locally and see if it shows up. If that doesn't work and you get tired of the problem, the `gulp-cli` package will fix it for sure, but that shouldn't be something you *have* to do.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I know of is to use `npm bin`:

```sh
`npm bin`/gulp ...
```

This keeps you away from hard-coding any paths.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was working for me. I followed all instructions from everyone. No matter what I did I could not run the Gulp commands.

To fix this I opened the Node.js command prompt that comes installed automatically when you download and run node.js.

Once I was in this command prompt I could run the following commands:

```
npm install -g gulp
gulp -v
```

This is probably a matter of common knowledge but as someone starting out no one suggested to run the node.js command prompt and install gulp from there. Everything I read talked about regular powershell or command prompts with elevated permissions.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -5):

Globally install gulp in C:\Users\%USERNAME% using this command

```
npm install –g gulp
```

You can install any other gulp methods you need to use.. Ex:

```
npm install -g gulp-concat
npm install -g gulp-uglify
npm install -g gulp-replace
```

Then at the directory you wish to use GULP. Open the command prompt (Shift + RightClick) then install locally and you'll be able to execute gulp.

```
npm install gulp
```

You can install any other gulp methods you need to use.. Ex:

```
npm install gulp-concat
npm install gulp-uglify
npm install gulp-replace
```

Comment: Like I have mentioned that I do not want to install gulp globally