# Husky and lint-staged unable to run gulp command

Tags: jquery, drupal, gulp, husky, lint-staged

Am trying to run gulp commands from package.json. But unable to execute.

This is my package.json.

```
  "scripts": {       
    "deploy": "gulp deploy",
    "lint": "eslint",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --ext .js"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*": [
      "gulp locale-sass", // not working
      "npm run lint", // working fine
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@open-tech-world/cli-progress-bar": "^1.0.6",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "console-table-printer": "^1.1.58",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-deprecate": "^0.7.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-changed": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-compass": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-consolidate": "0.2.0",
    "gulp-css-globbing": "^0.2.2",
    "gulp-debug": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-ext-replace": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sass-lint": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-scan": "^0.1.4",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.7.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-svg-symbols": "^3.2.3",
    "gulp-svgmin": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-terser": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jshint": "^2.11.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "2.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.2",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass-asset-functions": "^0.1.0",
    "npm-audit-resolver": "^2.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-lint": "^1.13.1",
    "through2": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

npm run lint is working fine.

Here gulp locale-sass is not working.

✖ gulp locale-sass && npm run lint:
Task never defined: &&

list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks

Using gulpfile /u02/home/user01/drupal/drupal-7.9/sites/medic/gulpfile.js

husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)

Comment: Have you tried `./node_modules/bin/gulp locale-sass`? Probably there's a problem resolving gulp locally vs globally when npm runs it. **UPD** Nah, I see it's not Gulp. It's local-sass only.

Comment: @vitkarpov nope. ./node_modules/bin/gulp locale-sass failed without output (ENOENT).

Comment: I have an idea, what if you move "gulp local-sass" into a npm command, just like npm run lint you already have? Would it be the same? First, can you run it as npm run sass (example name)? If yes, try to change it in lint-staged then.

Comment: @vitkarpov same result. Task never defined. It is same as it was earlier.

Comment: so, am I right that npm run sass doesn't work either?

Comment: @vitkarpov yes nope. Dosen't work. I wonder why gulp is not working here.

Comment: Right, please, try ./node_modules/.bin/gulp (and make sure gulp's included in your package.json and installed). Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677545/locally-installed-gulp-not-running-in-command-line

Comment: It's important to distinguish is it gulp or sass at this point.

Comment: @vitkarpov thanks. But it is still not working I tried ./node_modules/.bin/gulp locale-sass in package.json but same command in command promt it is working. Strange

Comment: I believe something's wrong with localization of sass when husky runs gulp.

Comment: Check out this one, maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048717/lint-staged-not-running-on-precommit

Comment: Husky is working fine. I want gulp to be executed. I u see linter is working fine except gulp command.

Comment: Do you have node-sass gulp-sass in your devDependencies?

Comment: I have updated the devDependencies, please have alook.

Comment: Please, update gulp to v4.0.1 and let me know. I found this issue https://github.com/cferdinandi/gulp-boilerplate/issues/76 in husky which looks pretty much the same as yours.

Comment: It seems like they got the problem back in v4.0.2 if it truly works with 4.0.1

Comment: I have updated "gulp": "^4.0.2", to "gulp": "^4.0.1", issue remains same.

Comment: If you could share your repo it'd be helpful.

Comment: I resolved this issue.I will post my answer soon. Thank you much appreciated.

Comment: No problem! I'd like to know what it was :-)

Comment: @vitkarpov I have done by adding locale-sass to script section and in lint staged npm run gulp locale-sass instead of gulp locale-sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by modifying srcipt section by adding `"locale-sass"` and in `lint-staged` `npm run gulp locale-sass` instead of `gulp locale-sass`

```
"scripts": {       
    "deploy": "gulp deploy",
    "lint": "eslint",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --ext .js",
    "locale-sass": "gulp locale-sass"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*": [
      "npm run gulp locale-sass", // Working
      "npm run lint", // working
      "git add"
    ]
  },
```