# 'Gulp' not found after installation?

Tags: gulp

Ive forked a repo and run npm install. I can see gulp is installed in the node_modules folder. However when I run gulp or gulp -v on the command line it says command not found.

If I open a new terminal in a different folder (which is outside of the repo eg my home folder) and run gulp -v I can see the version:

CLI version 3.9.0

So it seems gulp is installed both locally and globally but its still not working. I have gulp working find on another project that I previously set up.

This is a similar question but the solution posed does not work:
[no command 'gulp' found - after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224831/no-command-gulp-found-after-installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After completely deleting and re-cloning the repo its now working. Im not sure why but I did add this line:

```
PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"
```

To my bash profile:

```
~/.bash_profile PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"
```

And then on the command line ran:

```
npm config set prefix $HOME/.npm
```

This allows me to run npm install without sudo and so may or may not have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install gulp globally, most probably using sudo

```
sudo npm install -g gulp
```

this will ensure the command is available to you as you want

Comment: soudns like it's not - can you for example switch to another folder outside the repo and do

    gulp -v

Comment: Yes I've done this and I get the result: CLI version 3.9.0. Im not sure why it seems to be unclear but I did say this in my original question.

Comment: ok fair enough you didn't say the different folder was outside the repo - I would still run it again