# Intellij error gulp is not on your path

Tags: intellij-idea, npm, gulp

I'm running a project in intellij that uses gulp. 
After running the debug I get this error.

```
    | Error Error executing script RunApp: java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem executing execUiBuild.
standard out: 'Installing npm packages and running gulp.
gulp is not on your path. Make sure it is installed.
```

Anyone know how to fix this. I have gulp installed on my machine already.

Comment: Check the preferences in IntelliJ to see where in your PATH it is looking for gulp. Which OS are you running?

Comment: 10.10.4. I tried to find a PATH to gulp in the preferences but couldn't find one ? You know which of the preferences it is ?

Comment: Take a look at [gulp not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224831/no-command-gulp-found-after-installation) .

Comment: Thanks Simon but that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Intellij you can add Build/Run Configurations.

Depending on where you have Node installed and Gulp the paths will be different but here is where you can enter it for the project.

[image]

You can get to this screen by choosing **"Run" -> "Edit Configurations"**

If you haven't already setup a gulp task you can add one by choosing the **+** on the very top left of the window.

You can get the path to the installed version of node by doing the following command in a terminal:

```
which node
```

if you are using nvm it should return something like:

```
/Users/YOURUSERNAME/.nvm/v0.12.0/bin/node
```

Gulp should be in the /lib/node_modules/ folder of node that you have installed:

```
/Users/YOURUSERNAME/.nvm/v0.12.0/lib/node_modules/gulp
```

Those are the two paths that you need to get it up and running.

Comment: You can also setup a default for all your gulp tasks so that the **Node Interpreter** and **Gulp Package** paths are setup for each new configuration that you setup.