# Gulp Command not found ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, gulp

I'm having the weird issue i had installed gulp both locally and globally

but i m having the same issue when i type gulp command line it says "Gulp

Command Not found"

when i check npm root -g gulp was found in

**/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp**

Also i checked this by uninstalling the node js and reinstalling having the same issue :(

and i installed forever package and it is working but not gulp .. it there anyone who can help me out

Comment: Where did it install the executable?

Comment: **/usr/bin/node**

Comment: and **/usr/bin/nodejs**

Comment: try `gulp` instead of `Gulp`

Comment: Either export your path so `/usr/bin/node` is in your path or specify the full path.

Comment: Tried gulp same issue  :(

Comment: Not sure why it shows command not found message though it is intalled both locally and globally

Comment: what about npm install -g gulp-cli

Comment: I did it also but same result

Comment: I had figured out this i completly uninstall the node and reinstall it also there were broken paths not every thing is working thanks

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707907/5222115