# gulp: command not found

Tags: regex, node.js, laravel, npm, gulp

when i run gulp in cmd it says gulp: command not found

though when i checked

**npm root (Path Local)**

**/var/www/html/gus/node_modules**

**npm root -g (Path Global)**

**/Users/zohaib/npm-global/lib/node_modules**

i followed these rules though these are for OsX and im having ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I followed this link https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: npm install -g gulp-cli

Comment: Check the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707907/5222115

Answer (score 0):

To install gulp in Ubuntu, mentioned below are the steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install node`
2. `sudo apt-get install npm`
3. `sudo npm install --global gulp`
4. `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`
5. `sudo npm install`

Then run `gulp`.

Comment: i figured out this issue and re install the node and it worked like a charm

Comment: My mac was throwing the same error, following command resolved it - "sudo npm install --global gulp"