# Installing gulp in linux root but still getting gulp not found error

Tags: linux, npm, gulp

I want to install `gulp` in the root directory of `CentOS 7` but for some reason, after installation, it still says:

```
gulp: command not found
```

My `npm` version is `8.1.2` and `node` version is `16.13.2`. When I try to run `gulp -v` then I am returned with the gulp version as

```
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

But When  I try to run `sudo gulp -v` then I am returned with `gulp: command not found` while it does not happen with `npm` and `node`.

I have installed gulp with `npm install gulp -g`.

**Summary:**

I want to access gulp in the root directory by using `sudo` command. I have tried answers from [After installation of Gulp: “no command 'gulp' found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224831/after-installation-of-gulp-no-command-gulp-found) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707907/5222115
But none of them helped.

Comment: i think you need it in any bin directory rather than root directory

Comment: Actually I want to compile a js file with `gulp` but simply doing so does not render it on frontend. SO it might be the case I need to compile that file as a `root` user.

Comment: i know, but i mean you need the gulp to be installed in any bin folder like `/bin`, `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, i am not familiar with centos, so you need to study which one you should use for manually installed program

Comment: Ok sir thanks a lot