# "gulp" command is throwing an error "-bash: gulp: command not found"

Tags: html, node.js, npm, terminal, gulp-sass

I am trying to run gulp. I have set all the variables and task still it doesn't seem to work.

`

**this is the error i am getting**

[image: this is the error i am getting]
**this is my gulpfile.js setup**

[image: this is my gulpfile.js setup]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no command 'gulp' found - after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224831/no-command-gulp-found-after-installation)

Comment: @RuudHelderman I followed the link, it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add gulp path in your Environment Variables PATH