# $ gulp -> gulp: command not found, but $ npx gulp -> works?

Tags: gulp

I installed gulp as their documentation says, but I can not use "gulp" command, because it gives me "-bash: gulp: command not found" error. When I use "npx gulp" then it works, but I do not know why.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After installation of Gulp: “no command 'gulp' found”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224831/after-installation-of-gulp-no-command-gulp-found)

Comment: Ugh......images as code. Yucky.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install gulp locally and globally using `npm install` command on git bash and globally with `npm-g installl gulp-cli`. Then adding `gulp.cmd` path to windows path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but the short answer is that `npx` exists to solve this issue.

`npx` search your packages into `node_modules` directory instead of globally. If you have gulp installed globally, `gulp -v` should work fine. But `npx` solves this and also solves the problem with different packages versions in different projects.