# Trouble installing js-yaml NPM package dependancies on Ubuntu 64 bits

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, esprima

I am trying to get [my own project written on OSX](https://github.com/michahell/pinbored-webkit) to build on Ubuntu. It uses several npm packages to build itself. A few of them depend on the npm package js-yaml, which in it's turn depends on a package called 'esprima'. A fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installation gives me the error that this package can not be found:

> module.js:340
>       throw err;
>             ^
>   Error: Cannot find module 'esprima'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (/home/michahell/Documents/projects/pinbored-webkit/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml/type/js/function.js:4:15)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>   npm ERR! weird error 8
>   npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
>   npm WARN For further explanations, please read
>   /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

The output tells me that it might have something to do with the legacy binary node, but i should have solved this problem by symlinking node to point to nodejs, using this S.O. post:
[nodejs vs node on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04/18130296#18130296)

So, what is causing npm / node to not be able to find or install this package?

Answer (score 0):

So i have apparently solved this by manually installing the missing node module:

`npm install esprima`

Apparently, the npm module requiring this esprima module could just find it if it was 'locally' npm installed. If this is intended / deterministic behaviour, that's nice to know :)