# No response on typing 'node server.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a simple TODO MEAN application, with instructions from [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular).

server.js has the following nodejs related code.

**server.js**

```
// set up ========================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)

// configuration =================

mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:nodeuser@mongo.onmodulus.net:27017/uwO3mypu');     // connect to mongoDB database on modulus.io

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                 // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

On the Ubuntu terminal, On typing "node server.js" to run the server.

I am getting no response.

```
satyajit@Sunny:~/Documents/git repositories/mean-todo-app$ node server.js
satyajit@Sunny:~/Documents/git repositories/mean-todo-app$ node server.js
satyajit@Sunny:~/Documents/git repositories/mean-todo-app$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 7 satyajit satyajit 4096 Jun 28 11:03 node_modules
-rw-rw-rw- 1 satyajit satyajit  357 Jun 28 09:41 package.json
drwxrwxr-x 2 satyajit satyajit 4096 Jun 27 20:37 public
-rw-rw-rw- 1 satyajit satyajit 1455 Jun 28 09:41 server.js
```

Can anybody tell where am I going wrong or am I missing anything that needs to be done???

Comment: What happens if you type only `node` and hit Enter? Can you enter the node REPL?

Comment: On Ubuntu, `node` may not refer to Node.js. Try `nodejs server.js` instead. Also, [nodejs vs node on ubuntu 12.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Cool! Jonathan ... Thanks! I tried nodejs server.js. It worked.

Comment: BidhanA - On hitting node, no response came.

Comment: If I am using nodemon, what should be the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as Stated by Satyajit, ubuntu uses `nodejs server.js`.

I'll just say that people sometimes get all sort of problems because of it, since a lot of modules you install will assume the executable for node.js is `node` (not to talk about tutorials on the internet).

in order to get better compatibility, I suggest you run this command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

This will create a symbolic link for "node". Then, you can use

```
node server.js
```