# Compiling CoffeeScript with itself

Tags: compilation, coffeescript

I'm actually trying to recompile the CoffeeScript compiler made in CoffeeScript from the github repository, but I cannot recompile a single coffee source file.

I tried to install `coffee` compiler with `npm`, but it gaves me a `coffee` command that does this when I try to run:

```
coffee src/lexer.coffee
```

Or:

```
coffee -c src/lexer.coffee
```

> Error: In lexer.coffee, Parse error on line 115: Unexpected '...'
>       at Object.parseError (/usr/lib/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/parser.js:477:11)
>   at ...
>   [Long stacktrace here]

So how could I try to run directly a compiler present on github repository ? When I try to run `bin/coffee` or `bin/cake` executables scripts, even in root mode or with nodeJS, they print nothing and return 1.

Comment: Why do you want to recompile the compiler ?

Comment: And it's written in the documentation that you need to run `coffee -c path/to/source.coffee`. In your question you've forgot the `-c` argument I don't know if it's a mistake you'v done in the terminal.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin I've tried with **and** without -c flag. I updated my question to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: What do you get when you run `coffee -v` and `node -v`?

Comment: `coffee -v` and `node -v` both print nothing and still return 1. The same when I go into the cloned coffeescript repository and try to run `./bin/coffee -v`

Comment: It seems strange that the commands are not outputting anything. The error thrown in your question I think is because the version of coffeescript is too old to compile the latest version from github. But why you're not getting any output I don't know. Something swallowing your stdout?

Comment: @Chriskent The error of my question was in fact from an older version of coffeescript. But since I use the new one, whatever i give as flags or parameters, `coffee` and `cake` print nothing and return 1, the return value seems to indicate that something bad happened, doesn't it ?

Comment: @Aracthor Yes, you're right. But what that is I don't know. Is it possible that node has been installed as nodejs not node? Does`nodejs -v` work? Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18130164/450678

Comment: @ChrisKent The error was effectively comming from `nodejs`, and instructions on your link were sufficient to solve it. Please make an answer with it, the bounty is for you :)

Comment: @Aracthor Thanks, glad I could help. I've put an answer up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both

> When I try to run `bin/coffee` or `bin/cake` executables scripts, even in root mode or with nodeJS, they print nothing and return 1.

and

> `coffee -v` and `node -v` both print nothing and still return 1. The same when I go into the cloned coffeescript repository and try to run `./bin/coffee -v`

Indicate that nodejs is not correctly installed. (Or at least not installed as coffeescript expects). On some Linux installations another application can be installed as `node` and this can conflict with scripts that expect `node` to be nodejs. See related question: [nodejs vs node on ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18130164/450678)

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing [cake](https://github.com/shimaore/cake)? Looking at the CoffeeScript source, it appears that it is using `cake` as its build tool.

Unless I am missing something, the instructions in the README are not accurate in regards to building the project.

I was able to get the compiler to build by following these steps:

1. Clone the CoffeeScript repo.
2. Run `npm install` from the root of the CoffeeScript repo to install necessary dependencies.
3. Install cake: `npm install cake` (I hate personally dislike globally installing, so I always just install the deps local to the project.)
4. Run cake build: `./node_modules/.bin/cake build`
5. If no error, make sure the tests passed: `./node_modules/.bin/cake test`
6. Profit!

I am opening a PR right now to get these instructions updated in the README.

EDIT: Opened a PR for this: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/pull/4031