# nodejs express framework on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express

**Background information**

I'm trying my hand out at express.  I've been following the getting started guide found here:  http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html

**Problem**

I have nodejs installed have been creating on off files to check out how it works.  But here's what happened with my attempt to create an application using the generator:

```
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/node_express_tests$ sudo npm install express-generator -g
/usr/local/bin/express -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
express-generator@4.13.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator
├── sorted-object@1.0.0
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
└── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/node_express_tests$ express myapp
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/node_express_tests$ ls
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/node_express_tests$ sudo express myapp
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/node_express_tests$ ls
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/node_express_tests$ ls -lah
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 17 08:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jul 17 08:22 ..
```

If I understand correctly, I should have a directory structure that includes an app.js file as well as various directories. 
I'm not sure what I've done incorrectly.  I'm currently checking for some logs and also checking their documentation.  But any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

```
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/node_express+tests$ nodejs -v
v0.10.25
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/node_express_tests$ node -v
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/node_express tests$ npm -v
1.4.21
admin@devbox:~/Documents/nodejs/nimble$
```

Comment: try `/usr/local/bin/express myapp`. Also what's the output of `node -v` and `npm -v`?

Comment: this is interesting location. try in your home dir.

Comment: @Dodekeract, trying to launch express by prefixing the directory didn't do anything.  No errors, and no results.  Pls check out EDIT 1 in my post

Comment: @Andrey... i tried from my home directory, but it's the same thing.  No results.  I just get back my prompt.  No errors, no output

Comment: @dot I would suggest to try to debug express, since it is opensource. It is last resort.

Comment: @Andrey... hmm... sounds daunting.  But I will give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue is that you initially installed `node`, which on Ubuntu/Debian is some sort of HAM radio app. Node.js is called `nodejs`, but any external scripts will assume it's called `node` and therefore won't work properly. Uninstall `node` and check out [this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04).