# Forever nodejs won't run

Tags: node.js, forever

I have a problem with a server that runs nodejs.

For some reason, I need to say in the terminal nodejs instead of node.
I try to reinstall it many times, but It doesn't change it.

Now, this isn't a big problem but I need to run forever.
And forever won't run.

Is there a way to call forever with nodejs?

Thanks

Comment: Create a symlink, or perhaps install pm2 instead of forever. This may be a duplicate...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to forever [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). You can use `-c` flag to define the command to execute, which default to `node`.

So if you want to use `nodejs` instead. You could use `forever -c nodejs start script.js`

For this to work you need to create a symlink.

For exemple like this :
`ln -s /usr/local/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score 0):

install forever as a global

```
npm install -g forever
```

and run forever with this command inside application folder as this

```
forever start server.js
```