# Browsersync on Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, browser-sync

I did install [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/) on Ubuntu using command line:

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```

Now, I went to check for version:

```
browser-sync --version
```

where I get error message:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Is Node installed and on the `$PATH`?

Comment: @Biffen How to check?

Comment: First, check your memory: Have you installed Node? Other than that, `aptitude show nodejs`, `which node` and  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04), if it's still not solved.

Comment: `sudo npm install -g browser-sync`

Comment: @Biffen check yourself http://i.imgur.com/VMEBgWf.png

Comment: @mkinawy Sure I added sudo at the beginning ;)

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim And did you follow the link in my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed installing nodejs-legacy:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Then checked back to be worked:

```
ihab@ihab-pc:~$ node --version
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
ihab@ihab-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
[sudo] password for ihab: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs-legacy
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 122 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe nodejs-legacy all 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1 [14.6 kB]
Fetched 14.6 kB in 0s (32.9 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs-legacy.
(Reading database ... 232447 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs-legacy_0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs-legacy (0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Setting up nodejs-legacy (0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) ...
ihab@ihab-pc:~$ browser-sync --version
2.10.1
```

Thanks to @Biffen for his tip :)

Comment: you should only use the legacy package if you really need to e.g. because of an older system -> see my answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a symlink because the npm installer doesn't do it.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Its documented here:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: the legacy package mentioned by Ihab Abdel-Rahim solves the problem because apt-get install creates that symlink automatically -> so I advice not to install the lagecy package except your are on an older system and forced to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which I resolved by removing the problematic existing broken symlink and creating a new one:

- sudo rm /usr/bin/node
- sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

Hope it helps someone,
Cheers