# Node error Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, appium

I got an error when trying to install appium. It always says: node error.
Here is code: 
      sudo npm install wd

> wd@1.2.0 install /home/nataliya/node_modules/wd
>   node scripts/build-browser-scripts

sh: 1: node: not found
nataliya@1.0.0 /home/nataliya
├── json@9.0.6  extraneous
├── redis@0.7.3 
├── selenium-webdriver@3.4.0 
└── typescript@2.3.2

```
npm WARN nataliya@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN nataliya@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-77-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "wd"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! wd@1.2.0 install: `node scripts/build-browser-scripts`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the wd@1.2.0 install script 'node scripts/build-browser-scripts'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the wd package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build-browser-scripts
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs wd
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls wd
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/nataliya/npm-debug.log
```

And when I try to instal Appium, it comes up with this error:

```
  sudo npm install -g appium
  /home/nataliya/npm/bin/appium -> /home/nataliya/npm/lib/node_modules      /appium/build/lib/main.js
  /home/nataliya/npm/lib
  └── appium@1.6.4 

   npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /appium/fsevents:
   npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.1
```

Comment: I prefer to use [the official Node.js repository](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) to install Node.js on Ubuntu: it's much more up-to-date in terms of Node.js version, and it also installs the Node.js binary with the proper name (`node`, as opposed to `nodejs`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are victim of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04): `node` is installed in a way that you only have `nodejs` in `$PATH`, but you need `node`.

Comment: I am very grateful for the answer, any ideas how to fix that? Cheers

Comment: Have you checked the answers behind the link?

Comment: I did, yes. And what I got now is pretty same error.

Comment: What happens if you execute `which node` ?

Comment: /home/nataliya/.linuxbrew/bin/node

Comment: OK so you have `node` for your user, but not globally. Still not good. Have you made the symlink suggested in answer?

Comment: I followed all proposed steps under that link: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/nodejs because link group node is broken - that is what I got. I am really superconfused what could cause that issue