# Error Failed at the xxxx@1.4.0-rc.6 postinstall script 'typings install'

Tags: angularjs, npm, webpack, typescript-typings

I have following configuration, on giving command "npm install". I'm facing Error Failed at the xxxx@1.4.0-rc.6 postinstall script 'typings install' as provided below, can someone help me.

package.json:-

```
{
"name": "xxxx",
"version": "1.4.0-rc.6",
"description": "xxxx Dev with Angular 2, Express.js, Mongoose.js, Node.js",
"author": "Desh Raj",
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "typings install",
  "prestart": "webpack",
  "start": "concurrently \"webpack --watch --colors\" \"nodemon src/server.js\"",
  "typings": "typings"
},
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
  "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
  "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
  "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
  "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
  "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
  "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
  "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
  "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.23",
  "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
  "jquery": "^2.2.4",
  "mongoose": "^4.5.10",
  "morgan": "^1.7.0",
  "ng2-completer": "^0.2.3",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
  "systemjs": "0.19.27",
  "tether": "^1.3.6",
  "zone.js": "^0.6.17"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
  "nodemon": "^1.10.2",
  "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
  "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
  "typescript": "^1.8.10",
  "typings": "^1.3.3",
  "webpack": "^1.13.2"
}}
```

I perform "npm install -g typings" and also "npm install -g webpack", but still getting below error:-

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v4.2.6
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6~prestart: myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6
6 verbose lifecycle myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6~prestart: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6~prestart: PATH: /usr/share/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/ubuntu/mypleaks-angular/myPleaks/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
8 verbose lifecycle myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6~prestart: CWD: /home/ubuntu/mypleaks-angular/myPleaks
9 silly lifecycle myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6~prestart: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack' ]
10 info lifecycle myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6~prestart: Failed to exec prestart script
11 verbose stack Error: myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6 prestart: `webpack`
11 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
11 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:17:16)
11 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
11 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
11 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
11 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
12 verbose pkgid myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6
13 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/mypleaks-angular/myPleaks
14 error Linux 4.4.0-1013-aws
15 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
16 error node v4.2.6
17 error npm  v3.5.2
18 error file sh
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error errno ENOENT
21 error syscall spawn
22 error myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6 prestart: `webpack`
22 error spawn ENOENT
23 error Failed at the myPleaks@1.4.0-rc.6 prestart script 'webpack'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myPleaks package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     webpack
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs myPleaks
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls myPleaks
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Did you install `typings` globally ?

Comment: I tried to add that also using "npm install --save typings-global" but it didn't get installed, showing error as I edit the question.

Comment: You should use `npm install -g typings`

Comment: I perform "npm install -g typings" and also "npm install -g webpack", but still getting error as shown in the question(edited).

Comment: can you launch the command `webpack` from cli ?

Comment: I launched like this ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-146:~/mypleaks-angular/myPleaks$ webpack And got this error 
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

Comment: ok, It's maybe because your not nodejs binary is name `nodejs` and not `node`. Can you try to make a symlink ? you can follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04