# Upgrade the version of nodejs to 5.12.0

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-16.04, nvm, n

I tried to install node.js by **NVM** in Ubuntu 16.04 server by following [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04). And I got:

```
root@instance-15s8fbzx:/opt# nodejs --version
v4.2.6
root@instance-15s8fbzx:/opt# npm --version
5.3.0
root@instance-15s8fbzx:/opt# node --version
v8.4.0
```

Then, we I run a mean-stack project by `sudo npm start`, I got

```
class User {
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
```

Then, I saw [this link](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/264), I think maybe because the nodejs version is not correct. I have another server with `v5.12.0` as the version of `nodejs`, and the project worked well there.

Then, I tried to do

```
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.4.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node
```

But the version of the nodejs is still `4.2.6`. Does anyone know how to upgrade its version to `5.12.0`?

Comment: I think `nodejs` is the name used for the node binary in some Linux distributions. Both nvm and n install a binary named node. So you can ignore nodejs, or uninstall it using your distribution package manager.

Comment: For some info on the reason for the naming and how to use the Ubuntu package to get a binary called node: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed NVM and you have installed the necessary version of node, you select the node version as follows:

```
> nvm use v5.12.0
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the difference between "nodejs --version" and "node --version"?

Comment: The command-line tool for node is called "node", IE: "node --version" is using that command line tool, that's the one to use: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html

Comment: But I want to change the result of `nodejs --version` from `v4.2.6` to `v8.4.0`.

Comment: I don't know what the tool: nodejs is. It is not the CLI for Node

Comment: On some platforms like CentOS they install it as nodejs to avoid a name conflict with another binary already called node

Answer (score 0):

```
After upgrading to the Nodejs version, the following error occurred for the Laravel and VUE js packages I already had:
```

> PHP Fatal error: During inheritance of IteratorAggregate: Uncaught
> ErrorException: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::getIterator() should
> either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator():
> Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used
> to temporarily suppress the notice in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\clerk\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\ParameterBag.php:210

```
To solve the issue, I did the following:
```

1. composer update
2. npm update
3. npm run dev
4. php artisan serve

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).