# Can't create new Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular

Installed the Angular CLI using this command
    `npm install -g @angular/cli`
But when creating new project using command
`ng new PROJECT-NAME`
it shows

> You are running version v8.0.0 of Node.js, which is not supported by
>   Angular CLI v6.   The official Node.js version that is supported is
>    8.9 and greater. Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update  Node.js.

But actually i am using nodejs v9.11.1
[See screenshot of my cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgYWl.png)

Comment: Whats the result of `ng -v`?

Comment: first, do you mean angularjs or angular? second, can you share your output of `node -v`?

Comment: @Fussel `npm -v` is for the node package manager, not node

Comment: also, you are using nodejs v9, not node v9

Comment: @mast3rd3mon npm version is 6.0.1

Comment: but what is your `node -v` version? does it say v8.0.0?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon node -v shows v8.0.0

Comment: in which case, you need to install node 8.9 or higher

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Thank you, i thought its nodejs version

Comment: `nodejs -v` is something else, that command is invalid on my computer so its possibly a plugin or something?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly sounds like a version problem. The new angular cli version requires the latest version of node.

All you need to do is update node and npm to latest version , everything should work fine.

If you are working on windows I'd suggest just going on [their](https://nodejs.org/en/) site and getting the latest one(currently at the time of this post is 8.11.2). For linux based and mac I would suggest looking for a guide how to get latest version since installing from terminal with something like (apt-get install or yum) will not have latest version you need (can easily be changed with some simple commands)

Also do check the version of node with: node -v

There has also been a naming conflict on linux regarding node vs nodejs see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04).