# How to find nodejs version

Tags: node.js

I installed nodejs first with nvm but it didn't work as I expected.
When I installed it with LTS version `sudo yum -y install nodejs`, it worked but I'm not able to find the version of node.

```
node -v
-bash: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

I tried to remove nvm but still getting the same message.

Comment: `nvm deactivate` and `node -v`

Comment: Open the console and type node -v

Answer (score 6):

Use the traditional command

```
node --version
```

OR

```
node -v
```

If `nodejs -v` is working and above solutions not, refer this: [symbolic-link-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code ->

`$ node -v`

Answer (score 0):

In the command line just type the following

```
node --version
```

or you can use this code

```
node -v
```