# npm does not support Node.js v14.4.0

Tags: node.js, npm

everyone.

I am upgrading Node.js and npm in my Ubuntu 18.04.6 server, but I'm running into a strange problem.

I was using the process as indicated in the installation guides:
To install Node.js version 17.2.0, I use

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Then, to install npm version, I use

```
npm install -g npm
```

However, after this, when I try to use npm to install modules, I get the warning

> npm does not support Node.js v14.4.0
> You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
> can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.

Checking the versions of node, I find that

```
node --version
```

yields **v14.4.0**, but

```
nodejs --version
```

yields **v17.2.0**.

How do I fix it so node will point to the latest version and/or so npm will use the correct version of node?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: I would use `sudo` to install npm.

Answer (score 1):

I had also tried a lot for upgrading node version from 14 to 18. But even after installing latest version and following various procedures my version of node was showing 14.4.0 only.
Luckily following three node version manager commands solved my problem on my ubuntu machine v20.04.4:

```
1. curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
2. command -v nvm
3. nvm install node
```

Now check node has been updated to latest version and can be verified with `node --version`.

If you still find an old version even on installing new latest/lts version, then check which node version is set as default with following command:

```
nvm ls
```

you will see green colored version text set with an arrow in front of it. It will also show other versions which have installed recently like v16.15.0, v18.2.0, etc.
Change the node version you want to set by following command:

```
nvm alias default v18.2.0
```

After this close the terminal and restart the new terminal and try checking node JS version. Here you got you want..!!