# First time using node.js - "ReferenceError: node is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I just installed node.js. 
I tried writing node -v that should check the version - and it's not working. this is the output:

```
 > node -v ReferenceError: node is not defined 

at repl:1:2 at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21) 

at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12) 

at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17) 

at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10) 

at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8) 

at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14) 

at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10) 

at ReadStream.emit (events.js:98:17) 

at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12) >
```

I opened it using git - command: `node`

I tried running it using "Git", thought maybe that's the issue and I get the exact same output.

I am using windows 8 if it's relevant - followed this tutorial till now:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tlntE8fe6u4

http://youtu.be/FqMIyTH9wSg

How do I make it work?

Comment: have you tried restarting the git bash? may be restart your system?

Comment: I tried just now. nothing :(

Comment: try adding the following in your path variable: C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Comment: ^ I'm not sure what that means @amyn. 
I tried running it using CMD and I got the same output

Comment: Right click on My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings on the left side -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables.. -> System Variables -> Double click on Path and append the following without quotes: ";C:\Program Files\nodejs\" I assume the above path is where nodejs is installed on your system

Comment: nothing changes. I tried restarting too.

Comment: Maybe I am looking at this a completely wrong way. but for trying, look at the following path and see if node.exe is present there or not "C:\Program Files\nodejs"

Comment: It's there. 
I uninstalled it and installed 32 bit which installs it to "Program Files (x86)" folder. 
same problem..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65761/discussion-between-amyn-and-hatul).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It looks like you have entered the [node REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) and then typed `node -v`

The good news is that this means node is working!

To check the version from here you can type `process.version` to get the node version. Alternatively type `process.exit()` to exit the node REPL and get back to bash (or equivalent terminal).

From here `node -v` should just output the node version.

Comment: Based benbrunton to the rescue.

Comment: @benbrunton So, what is this process then? just a simple nodejs process? trying to run .js files? thanks :)

Comment: To answer your question, this is the nodejs [REPL module](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html). When node is installed it's functionality becomes associated with various commands (via above mentioned system variables 'path' association). Once installed, running node.exe from windows is not necessary to run js files. From cmd, bash, and I'd imagine git etc you can simply use the commands `$ node myfile.js` from the current directory.

Answer (score 49):

### Edit

> First time using node.js

Although already answered, but just putting in my 2-cents,

Normally, the first time users would trip over it, so am posting some screen shots, and that OP wants to try `node -v`, so making it a bit *easier* to follow.

### The Wrong !!

[image: Win+S> Node // or you open it by some other way]

[image: then you try here 'node -v' , which throws error]

---

### The Correct !!

[image: Here it should work as expected]

---

### or you can do ..

[image: then you have to go with another command]

Hope it helps someone.!

Comment: When I type node -v I am getting "ReferenceError: node is not defined". but process.version option worked for me, thanks

Comment: @Shamli You check **the Wrong** and **the Correct** in the post.. you should get it working by `node -v` as well

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that

Comment: This answer is more clear to see the difference. Thank you @Irf .Adding another Info, when I searched for cmd, a specific 'Node.js command prompt' also showed. Entered into there and tried thr node -v. Worked.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of node.exe, try to run node from "**Node.js command prompt**".

First, you should install nodejs.msi from [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/).

Once installation is completed, go to: **Start** > **All Programs** > **Node.js** > **Node.js command prompt**.

It worked for me.

Comment: Where this "Node.js command prompt" comes from? Please post a link for documentation to understand you better

Comment: You should install nodejs.msi from nodejs.org and then after installation is completed go to: Start>All Programs>Node.js>Node.js command prompt. It worked for me

Comment: In Node.Js v4.4.7 the start menu item that is written about in this comment **is** node.exe, which you can observe by right clicking/properties. Obviously this worked for someone but see my comment above about how you **do not** want to be in node.exe to use the original node command.

Comment: After installing Node.js I was able to start a command prompt and type "Node" or "Node -v" to show the version, but when I tried to use npm (or rather "npm -v") to show the version, it gave the message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: npm is not defined". When I ran Node from the All Programs ("All apps" on windows 11) menu as you have described, it worked. Thank you.
(Probably a path or variable issue resolved by using the specific "node.js command prompt")

Answer (score 4):

Even I faced the same when I install the NODE server and Try to execute "node-v" command from directly clicking on start up menu's NODE ICON.
Instead of doing that all you need to do is GO TO command prompt then go to C:/program files/node path and type "node -v" command it will definitely  going to display you the version of NODE.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try opening up a new terminal (Run -> CMD) and then executing:

```
node /your_file_name.js
```

And to see which version you have installed, just execute:

```
node -v
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow below Steps:

1. Open command prompt: **RUN > CMD**
2. Navigate to folder where nodejs is installed: **C:\users\name>cd path_of_nodejs**
3. Open nodejs: **C:\path_of_nodejs>node**
4. Exit from node REPL mode: **>process.exit()**
5. You are ready for your node commands: **>node -v**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this help.

If you are using windows, like me, and want a desktop shortcut and you already have the nice node.js desktop icon, edit the shortcut properties like this:

1. right click and select properties
2. click change Icon, select the current icon and click OK (to lock it in)
3. in the target box, change it all to simply say cmd or c:\windows\System32\cmd.exe if you are pedantic.

now you have a command prompt, with the node.js icon, that opens in the folder you expect, that responds correctly to the node -v command.