# Node version command

Tags: node.js

Solution may be pretty easy but I am a newbie so forgive me. Even I could launch the `Node.js REPL` and play around (create objects ,make calculations),the simple command below:

```
$ node --version
```

doesn't work.It says:

> "Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier" .

I am trying to write this to Node.js command prompt.I am using Windows 10.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888471/node-js-version-on-the-command-line-not-the-repl

Comment: When you say *"I am trying to write this to Node.js command prompt"* are you running the command **within** the `node` REPL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run `node --version` from outside of the `node` REPL. If you want to get the version from within the REPL you can use:

```
$ node
> process.versions.node
'0.12.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm version` instead:

zag2art@home:~/$ npm version

```
{ npm: '2.10.1',
  http_parser: '2.3',
  modules: '14',
  node: '0.12.4',
  openssl: '1.0.1m',
  uv: '1.5.0',
  v8: '3.28.71.19',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
```

Enter it in the console, bash for example...

Comment: The versions of npm and the version of node are not synchronized. You can update one without updating the other, depending upon your process.