# How to get version of node from docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

To [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888471/node-js-version-on-the-command-line-not-the-repl) a node version - I expect to run the following:

```
node --version
```

I'm running the following with docker:

```
docker run node:4-onbuild -v
```

I get this:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '--version' not found or does not exist..
```

My question is: **How to get version of node from docker container?**

Comment: Could you try `docker run -it --rm node /bin/bash -c 'node --version'`

Comment: your command `docker run node:4-onbuild -v` does launch a node:4 docker container, and tries to launch the command `-v` which is not a valid bash command, see Kunkka's answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to specifically ask docker to run `-v` within the node container like below

```
docker run -it --rm node /bin/bash -c 'node --version'
```

Comment: In case one uses `node:alpine` or other distributions who have no `bin/bash` available, you can use `docker run -it --rm node:alipne node`. It will start node console with version info in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply type "docker run node -v"

Comment: You still need to specify the image, so we could do something like you mentioned: `docker run -it node:latest /usr/local/bin/node -v` or with short form: `docker run -it node node -v`

Comment: Try to give explanation to your answer, people also understand why one or other solution works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).