# 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I tried running npm install -g angular-cli

[image]

I also tried adding it to the Enviorment Variables under PATH: (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng) , with no success also.
[image]

Comment: restart command line shell, it uses cached PATH

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ng is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991556/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: for me, this solved the problem:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1183

Comment: Might take a look at this tutorial: [ng not recognized as an internal or external command](https://semicolon.dev/angular/how-to-fix-ng-is-not-recognized-as-internal-command-error)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This error is simply telling you that Angular CLI is either not installed or not added to the PATH. To solve this error, first, make sure you’re running Node 6.9 or higher. A lot of errors can be resolved by simply upgrading your Node to the latest stable version.

Open up the Terminal on macOS/Linux or Command Prompt on Windows and [run the following command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14888509/11398730) to find out the version of Node you are running:

```
node --version
```

Comment: It didn't for me; could anyone advise please?

Comment: in the windows command i tried
 "npm run ng  build" and it worked fine thank you

Comment: `npm run ng test` in the command prompt give me: npm ERR! missing script: ng .
   I installed @angular/cli globally (npm install -g @angular/cli)

Answer (score 137):

You can also try:

```
 > npm run ng <command>
```

Answer (score 80):

I had the same issue on Windows7. I resolved it setting correct path.

1. First find ng.cmd file on your System. It will usually at:

   ```
   E:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm
   ```
2. Set `PATH` to this location.
3. Close existing command window and open new one
4. Type

   ```
   ng version
   ```

Also remember to install angular with -g command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: This should be the valid answer.

Comment: I had to also add the E:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli folder to the path in order for it to work

Comment: executing npm install -g @angular/cli solved my issue. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 50):

You should not add `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng` to your PATH. There is only a javascript file which you cannot use in terminal.

You need `ng.cmd` which is probably located at `%AppData%\Roaming\npm`.
Make sure this path is included in your PATH variable.

Comment: i had done something similar, added /node_modules in path. Thanks

Comment: `%AppData%\Roaming\npm` should be `%AppData%\npm`

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal It depends on your setup. In this case, OP has `prefix` of  `npm` set to `%AppData%\Roaming\npm`

Answer (score 13):

I was with the same problem and now discovered a working solution. 
After successful installation of node and angular CLI do the following steps.

Open `C:\usr\local` and copy the path or the path where angular CLI located on your machine.

[image]

Now open environment variable in your Windows, and add copied path in the following location:

`Advanced > Environment Variable > User Variables and System Variables` as below image:

[image]

That's all, now open cmd and try with any 'ng' command:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You should add the path where ng.cmd located. By default, it should be located on ***C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm***

NB: Here "user" may vary as per your pc username!

Answer (score 8):

make sure  environment variables are set properly.

```
control panel-> system->advanced system settings-> select advanced Tab->
click on environment variables
```

and make sure in the path below line is available

```
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm`
```

here username will get changed based on the user

.

still if its not working yourenvironment variables are not getting reflected
so please restart your machine it will work fine

if still you are facing issue 
your angular cli is not installed properly

please run below commands for reinstalling

```
   npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

    npm cache clean    or   npm cache clean  --force

    npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` command worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Just adding a little info to the previous answers, If you have windows 7 or above then go to start and search **Node.js command prompt** and you will be directly shown the app. Click on it, and start working by using that command prompt for angular.

Comment: Thanks, man! It solved my problem in which I was stuck for days

Answer (score 7):

This answer is based on the following answer by @YuSolution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622211/4567504.

In my case Installing MySQL changed my path variable and even after reinstalling @angular/cli globally many times I was not able to fix the issue.

**Solution:**

In command prompt, run the following command

```
npm config get prefix
```

A path will be returned like

> C:\Users{{Your_Username}}\AppData\Roaming\npm

Copy this path and go to ControlPanel > System and Security > System, Click on Advanced System settings, go to advanced tab and select environment variable button like

[image]

Now in **User Variables** box click on **Path** row and edit and in **variable value** box paste your copied path.

Restart the command prompt and it will work

Answer (score 3):

*note: you may lose values once system restarts.*

You can also add system environment variables without Admin rights in Windows 10.

[image: Go to Control panel --> user accounts]

[image: Change my environment variables]

[image: environment variables --> select **Path** and click edit]

[image: click **New** and add path to it]

**now don't restart, close any opened cmd or powershell**, **reopen cmd and test by *ng version* command** if you see this it is confirmed working fine.

[image: ng version --> Angular cli]

*hope this helps*

Answer (score 2):

If angular cli is installed and ng command is not working then please see below suggestion, it may work

In my case problem was with npm config file (.npmrc ) which is available at C:\Users{user}. That file does not contain line 
`registry https://registry.npmjs.org/=true`. When i have added that line command started working. Use below command to edit config file. Edit file and save. Try to run command again. It should work now.

```
npm config edit
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set any path. Follow the below step to resolve the problem-

Step 1- go to

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming and delete npm, npm-update and npm-cache folder
```

Step 2- run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@yourangularversion again.
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to uninstall angular/cli.

1. You just need to make sure the PATH to npm is in your environment PATH and at the top.

`C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm`

2. Then close whatever git or command client your using and run `ng-v` again and should work

Answer (score 2):

I have tried with this below Steps and its working fine:-

Download latest version for nodejs, it should work

Comment: I tried reinstalling angular cli and messing with Windows PATH, neither worked. Installing latest version of nodejs as suggested fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed angular cli and it solved my issue, simply run:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was that I was missing an file

```
.npmrc
```

which is located under

```
C:\Users\username
```

That file should contain

```
prefix=$(APPDATA)\npm
```

Also my environment path was pointing to my admin user

Answer (score 1):

npm update solves the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

This issue also bother me and then i find possible cases to reproduce this issue

when i run my window in administrator then it working fine
**ng** but when i run this in my second space like other user then i got this issue.

so if i want to run my angular application then i need to run this command

**npm run ng serve** which is working
but when i run the command with **--host**  **npm run ng server --host IP** it not working given some error

so i find some possible solution
1. go **appdata** and then **user\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm folder** then copy this path but if you using other user account **user\newuser\AppData\Roaming\npm folder** you can copy this npm folder from other user i.e admin user account. 
if you do not want to copy this folder then copy the path of ****user\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm folder**** folder and then open your environment variable setting and add this path in path variable name

enter this path in **system path variable** not user variable
**C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm**

[image]
[image]
and run the command prompt as administrator then run **ng** command it will work
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Just install the latest version of [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) and then restart your system.

more description:

It's related to Environment variables in your system at least as far as I know, you can make changes in path variable in your system as others talked about it in the current thread but the easiest way to solve this is installing nodejs!