# 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

After removing the previous version of Node.js , now i have installed the latest version of it. I have also installed @angular/cli .

[image]

But when i am trying to create new Project through CLI , i am getting error

> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I have uninstalled Node.js several time using command and manually all folder but still it coming after fresh installation.

I have tried to install @angular/cli but getting below error.

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you reinstall the angular with `-g` argument?

Comment: how did you install @angular/cli? did you restart the command line after installing it? run the following `$ npm list -g --depth=0` , what does it show?

Comment: Well clearly angular cli is not installed properly if `ng` is not available. 

`npm install -g @angular/cli` 

On Windows it's best to do that using the powerShell and need to be run as admin and it will work in windows shell too.

Comment: @AnkitSaroch : You are talking about installing  npm  install  -g @angular/cli  command right  ? Yes i have done that .

Comment: @Maximus : After running the command it show  C:\Users\Naveen\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

Comment: well, then there's no angular cli installed, install it again

Comment: @Maximus : I have tried to  run  npm install -g @angular/cli  but after some warning  i am getting  below error :                                                              npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-2.0.0.tgz failed, reason: 0:error:1408F10B:SSL ro
utines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:365

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: It might be related to your npm configuration. Make sure your npm modules folder is included in your PATH  variable. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669589/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-b/44670398#44670398

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner : The Value of PATH variable in my system is  **C:\Users\Naveen\AppData\Roaming\npm** . Is it correct as per your link. After that i have tried to install Angular cli from Node.js command prompt but  getting        below error :                                                                    npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-4.0.13.tgz failed,
reason: 0:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:opens
sl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:365:    What is the meaning of this error ??

Comment: Clear your cache and npm modules folder. Run `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` then `npm cache clean`. Then try to install again.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner : Done as per your steps . And now got different error .                                                                                                     error code EINTEGRITY
9937 error sha1-EFSVrlNh1pe9GVyCUZLhrX8lN4c= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-EFSVrlNh1pe9GVyCUZLhrX8lN4c= but got sha1-pLtK76MhhKNKR1lsvcj12M8TE9Q=. (48626 bytes)

Comment: I have no idea what that error is. I suggest you start over

Comment: Thank you all of you for supporting me . Thanks you so much.

Comment: Hi All .. I have executed  **npm install mssql** from command prompt and it worked successfully but  **npm install -g @angular/cli** command  is throwing error while executing .

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons.

1. It could be you do not have npm folder on your `PATH` after installing Angular (`npm install @angular/cli -g`)

Append the below entry in your system or user environment variable:
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm

Open a new windows shell and `ng` command should be available.

> ng -v

```
 
   _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.2 Node: 6.9.2 OS: win32 x64 Angular: ...
```

2. Your Angular version is corrupted. As of Angular 5 you don't need to clean the cache. It self-heals from corruptions.
   To check if the cache is corrupted, use

   > npm cache verify

For older version of Angular, uninstall using:

> npm uninstall -g angular-cli
>   npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli

To install new version, use:

> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
>   npm cache clean
>   npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to solve this by using  **`NodeJS`** command prompt rather Windows Command, **`NodeJs`** command prompt will recognize **`ng`**.

Comment: I have tried with Node.js command prompt but getting same error :        npm ERR! request to registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-2.0.0.tgz failed, reason: 0:error:1408F10B:SSL ro utines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:365

Answer (score 0):

I did everything above to no avail. Uninstalled VS2017 and NodeJS. After reinstalling NodeJS and angular cli still had same problem. I did a npm get and noticed it was installed in an old folder "c:\programdata\microsoft\visualstudio\mda\taco-toolset.x.x.x.." which made no sense all VS version were completely gone. 
It ended up being a file in "c:\users\yourUsername\.npmrc" was the problem as it is not removed after uninstalling NodeJs. Delete that file and reinstall NodeJs , Angular CLI and all was good. This may have been a result of installing VS2017 with NodeJs tools as part of it but am not 100% sure on that.