# 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, Angular tutorial

Tags: node.js, angular

I"m doing [this tutorial for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-mongodb-nodejs-part2). It's when I come to running the following

```
ng new angular-cosmosdb -sd src/client --minimal --style scss
```

I get the error message "'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command," when I can confirm that Angular has been installed globally - as below

I've tried solutions here,

['ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995810/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

namely

o reinstall the angular with -g argument (even though this was already installed globally)
o restart, restart, restart laptop again and again and again
o my suspicion is that an local variable might need to be set? But other than that..

output from the list command is:

```
C:\2017\12 December\04122017\project>npm list -g --depth=0
D:\Users\useradmin\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@1.5.5
`-- typescript@2.6.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are experiencing this in Windows, Try setting the PATH as,

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\[YOUR_WINDOWS_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

In case if you are using it in OSX,

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

which will make the `ng` command work.