# How to check and change the Nodejs version on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu Linux.

How can I check current `nodejs` version? I guess, I have 6 version, but I am not sure.

And is there way to change it, because I need 4 version. Can some one give step by step commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js version on the command line? (not the REPL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888471/node-js-version-on-the-command-line-not-the-repl)

Comment: You can use NVM (Node version management) to manage multiple active node.js versions. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Open up the terminal and type `node -v`

To change your node version, I'd recommend installing [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). Once installed, to switch versions it's as simple as

```
nvm use <version>
```

Answer (score 26):

You can check your current NodeJS version by using command **node -v**.
And changing your version can be done by using node version manager.
The easiest way to do that is by running this **$ npm install -g n** now you can change your current NodeJS version using **n (version)**
e.g. n 4.0.0.

```
node -v
npm install -g n
n 4.0.0
```

Comment: This does not change the active version. How do I change to the stable version, for instance.  I tried:<br/>
# n latest<br/>
  installing : node-v15.7.0<br/>
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/15.7.0<br/>
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v15.7.0/node-v15.7.0-linux-x64.tar.xz<br/>
   installed : v15.7.0 to /usr/local/bin/node<br/>
      active : v10.13.0 at /opt/conda/bin/node<br/>
# n stable<br/>
   installed : v14.15.4 to /usr/local/bin/node<br/>
      active : v10.13.0 at /opt/conda/bin/node<br/>

Comment: Yes, this is annoying, what I ended up doing was removing node (https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04) and then you can either symlink /usr/local/bin/[node~npm] into /usr/bin or you can add /usr/local/bin to your path.

Comment: NOTE: When you run it, n will inform you that node might not report the correct version until you restart your CLI. So, be sure to do so

Answer (score 10):

You can check your version by using this code (`node -v`) in linux terminal and If you want to upgrade it to stable version you can use following codes one by one.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Answer (score 3):

To change your node version, I'd recommend installing `nvm`. Once installed, switch versions follow the instruction below;

`nvm use <any specified version you prefer "example v16.0.0">`

Example:

```
nvm alias default 16
```

This will enforce as the current default version.

Answer (score 2):

Just type `npm version` in your command line and it will display all the version details about node, npm, v8 engine etc.